# StackOverflow недостаточно дружелюбен. Настало время это исправить

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, новые-участники, перевод-блога

*Данное сообщение является переводом статьи Джея Хенлона «[Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/)».*

#### Предупреждение: этот пост описывает, прежде всего, ситуацию на англоязычном Stack Overflow. Пожалуйста, не воспринимайте его как попытку обвинить в чем-либо как русскоязычное сообщество в целом, так и отдельных его участников.

---

Мы любим Stack Overflow и верим в него. Но порой, при всей заботе и любви, мы вынуждены признавать, что у нас есть проблемы.

**Давайте посмотрим правде в глаза:**

- Очень много людей воспринимают Stack Overflow¹ как враждебное место и элитный клуб. В большинстве своём это начинающие программисты, женщины, представители не титульных наций и прочие потенциально притесняемые группы *(именно такое определение EIGE [даёт](http://eige.europa.eu/rdc/thesaurus/terms/1280) для словосочетания «marginalized groups» — прим. пер.)*.
- Наши сотрудники и сообщества уже давно занимаются этой проблемой, но предпочитали не говорить прямо о её существовании и не уделяли ей должного внимания. Однако конечный результат важнее всяких желаний.

Нет, это не из-за того, что большинство участников Stack Overflow — закомплексованные злопыхатели. Большинство-то как раз доброе и великодушное. Однако активные участники регулярно высказывают своё разочарование в том, что мы не делаем ничего для создания уюта сторонним посетителям. И это проблема не сообщества, а наша.

Мы обучили участников указывать другим на их ошибки, но не рассказали новичкам, как этих ошибок избежать. Мы не давали нашим опытным участникам подходящих средств для поиска того, что им нужно. И наконец, мы так и не определились, являемся ли мы сайтом для «экспертов» или для всех.

[image: Фигурка LEGO единорога]

### Да, у нас серьёзные проблемы

Откуда мы узнали, что большое число разработчиков считает Stack Overflow недружелюбным? Проблемы, связанные с чувствами, хороши тем, что они лежат на поверхности — люди сами говорят о них. Достаточно просто прислушаться. И мы знаем о недоброжелательности SO к разработчикам именно потому, что они сами нам об этом пишут.

Stack Overflow *изначально* был задуман как всеобъемлющее место для любого программиста. [Это решение было одним из первых, принятых Джоэлом и Джеффом](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2018/04/23/strange-and-maddening-rules/). Но это место отталкивает тех, кто не знает всех его принципов. Очень часто кто-то приходит сюда, задаёт вопрос и слышит в ответ только то, что он сделал это неправильно. Ему ехидно или снисходительно разъясняют, что он забыл описать свои попытки решения. Затем кто-то публикует ответ... И отвечающего раскритиковывают за то, что он поощряет низкокачественные вопросы, а ответ при этом заминусовывается! Но иногда вопрошающий всё-таки дожидается ответа. В благодарность он пишет ответившему «спасибо»... только чтобы услышать, что благодарности на Stack Overflow являются бесполезным шумом. **Всё это в сумме и даёт впечатление об SO как о месте, недружелюбном для масс.**

[image: Фигурка LEGO рабочего]

### Нам тяжело, потому что мы в ответе за то, куда мы вложили всю свою любовь

Беспокойство по этой проблеме не ново для нас. Инициатива «[Summer of Love](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/)», [пересмотр причин закрытия](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/), [пересмотр политики *be-nice*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/357761) и [апробирование наставничества](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357198/2553424) появились из-за нашего желания создать место, приветливое к каждому. Однако мы не осознавали всей серьёзности проблемы и не уделяли ей достаточно сил.

Мы упустили из виду следующее: **конструктивную критику порой трудно принять, особенно касательно особой недружелюбности к женщинам и национальным меньшинствам**. Это связано с парадоксом предвзятости. По идее, те из имеющих привилегии, кто принимает меры против предвзятости, и должны быть назначены на позиции, связанные с помощью другим. Однако трудно осознать, что мы сами непредумышленно предвзяты². К примеру, я боюсь, что кто-то почувствует себя обделённым. Забавно, но именно этот страх мешает осознать, что мои действия как раз и могут привести к обделённости. Из-за этого я сосредоточился на том, чем мы гордились. Мы единственный крупный сайт, на котором практически невозможно найти ни единого оскорбления — сообщество удаляет подобное крайне быстро. Мы не позволяем называть женскую часть нашего сообщества «пусечками» и флиртовать с ней. Однако мы ни к кому не прислушиваемся. Большое количество людей, особенно из уже упомянутых групп, не сильно чувствуют дружелюбности. И они пишут об этом нам.

**Мы чувствовали себя в ответе за наших пользователей**, потому что они приходят сюда учить, а большинство из них к тому же являются борцами во имя добра.

**Однако мы, как и любая другая компания, имеем бесконечный список запланированных дел при ограниченных ресурсах.** В последние годы охват, как и любая вопросно-ответная деятельность, был где-то на уровне «настолько важно, что находится... Э-м... *Где-то* на третьем месте в списке последовательных действий», что означало практически полное отсутствие направленных на него усилий.

[image: Фигурка LEGO женщины и компьютера]

### Принимаемся за решение проблемы (ниже перечислено, с чего стоит начать)

Всю последнюю неделю мы рассматривали ситуацию вне очереди, задействовав команды, ответственные за руководство, сообщества, данные, проектирование, исследования и инженерную часть. Мы прислушались к сообществам и тем, кто поделился своим опытом. Хочу поблагодарить всех, кто высказался о необходимости изменений. Неприятно признавать, но мы нуждались в этом.

Мы начали с опроса пользователей и мы до сих пор открыты для ваших идей. Есть возможность проанализировать сайт на предмет широты охвата. Возможно, стоит пересмотреть правила касательно нежелательности благодарностей. Это правило служит для повышения уровня полезного сигнала, однако оно также намекает, что мы, возможно, цукенботы, даже не пытающиеся замаскироваться под людей *(это отсылка к [мему «Цукенберг — не человек» в общем и слушанию в Сенате США в апреле 2018 года в частности](https://tjournal.ru/68933-vystuplenie-marka-cukerberga-v-kongresse-ssha-snova-dokazalo-chto-on-ne-chelovek) — прим. пер.)*. Как бы то ни было, есть несколько областей, на которых всем нам необходимо сосредоточиться:

1. **Перейдите от *«не вести себя агрессивно»* к *«быть дружелюбным»*.** Многие участники ещё не осознают, что у нас есть [кодекс поведения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) (из-за его несерьёзного названия), и что в нём содержатся такие вещи, как *«оскорбления — это плохо»* и *«Будьте дружелюбными, терпеливыми ... Не ожидайте от новых участников знания всех правил — это невозможно»*. Поэтому мы должны ознакомить с ним *всех* участников и дать им возможность воплощать этот кодекс в жизнь. В долгосрочной перспективе я хочу получить то, о чём [Джон Скит](https://blog.jonskeet.uk/) поведал, описывая [свои впечатления по поводу посещения им гей-парада в Сиетле](https://plus.google.com/+JonSkeet/posts/R2qfffbDwW2) (в качестве цисгендерного гетеросексуального мужчины): «Я был не просто толерантным с ними. Я чувствовал, что это сообщество улучшилось благодаря моему присутствию рядом с ним».
2. **Сделайте что-нибудь с комментариями.** Снисходительный тон и сарказм неохотно, но считались допустимыми в комментариях. Мы внесём некоторые изменения в движок, но надо начать работу с сообществами и их управляющими, чтобы поднимать тревоги на подобных сообщениях уже сейчас.
3. **Дайте новым участникам преуспеть.** Нет, я не перекладываю ответственность. Именно мы являемся причиной их неудач, и наши влиятельные участники постоянно просили нас, чтобы мы им помогли. Сейчас мы тестируем новую, стартовую форму публикации вопросов, в которой поле тела вопроса разбито на несколько частей, каждая из которых предназначена для своей детали, обязательной для качественного вопроса:

   - «Что ожидалось?»
   - «Что получилось? Дополните детальной информацией об ошибке.»
   - «Вставьте сюда как можно более короткий блок кода, позволяющий воспроизвести ошибку. Не волнуйтесь, мы его отформатируем.»
   - «Что вы уже пытались сделать? Дополните информацией о ваших предварительных исследованиях и т. д.»
4. **Прекратите осуждать людей за их незнание. В конце концов, мы сайт вопросов и ответов.** Меня огорчает, когда кого-то минусуют за вопросы-дубликаты. Конечно, мы должны их выявлять, но это не значит, что сами спрашивающие должны это делать на постоянной основе. В конце концов, пользователи не ленятся искать — это занимает куда меньше времени чем собственно формулирование вопроса.

   Ещё больше меня огорчают комментарии вида «не отвечайте на подобные вопросы — вы поощряете их публикацию». Да, некоторые вопросы не вписываются в тему сайта. Но как же здорово отвечать на вопрос, зная, что никто не поднимет вонь насчёт допустимости чего-либо *(это я ещё смягчил и локализовал; в оригинале Джей позволил себе фразу «without giving a grilled poop sandwich» в, на секунду, официальном блоге компании — прим. пер.)*. Также приятно работать добровольцем без обязательства читать и чтить абсолютно все правила и все дискуссии на Мете, когда-либо опубликованные.
5. **Прекратите проводить границу между качеством и добротой.** Качество, конечно, важно — благодаря ему сообщения помогут большему количеству людей. Но бо́льшее и более развитое сообщество и так производит артефакты лучшего, не худшего качества. Нам надо прекратить оправдывать снисходительное отношение к участникам во имя стремления к качеству и дать влиятельным пользователям средства для его поддержания на высоком уровне.

[image]

### Мы продолжаем любить и гордиться тем, чего мы достигли совместными усилиями

Каждый день десятки тысяч людей откладывают свои дела и идут на SO, чтобы помочь интернет-странникам. И миллионы раз в день люди не сдаются и справляются с трудностями в проектах благодаря решениям, безвозмездно даваемым здесь. Я невероятно горд за ту малую роль, которую я играю во всём том, чего достигло сообщество. Наши участники воистину самые щедрые люди на планете. Но мы можем стать лучше. Вместе мы превратим мир в одно большое техническое сообщество, объединённое культурой, которой мы гордимся; в место, ставшее лучше только потому, что вы здесь.

*Мы ищем тех, кто готов поделиться с нами своим опытом и помочь нам определить наиболее важные вещи для воплощения в жизнь. Являетесь ли вы активным пользователем или тем, кому здесь не нравится, вы можете помочь, приняв участие в [коротком опросе](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCQNtu4KHesQz-2AzRSl8z6d4_cLgPj4B7cjNpPePc-04seA/formResponse).*

---

¹ В данной статье речь идёт только о Stack Overflow на английском, но её тезисы применимы и к другим сайтам сети.

² Если вы думаете, что вас это уж точно не касается, пройдите [тесты на скрытую предвзятость](https://implicit.harvard.edu/implicit/index.jsp), особенно на расовую (Race IAT) и карьерно-половую (Gender-Career IAT). Если вы психологически похожи на меня, результат вас поразит.

Comment: Вот по теме: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/does-stack-exchange-really-want-to-conflate-newbies-with-women-people-of-color

Comment: Влад, очень толковый пост. Для себя тоже поделил вопрос на две части. "Hostility against newbies is borne of terrible newbie questions. SE forces us to constantly interact with a stream of garbage". А вторая часть (про женщин, цветных и "другие маргинализированные слои") вообще как-то слабо применима именно к so русскоязычному. Хотя возможно, нам тоже придётся найти у себя на сайте женщин, цветных а потом дружно в духе решений ЦК КПСС "углу́бить и расширить". Интересно, а есть тесты на скрытую предвзятость адаптированные для России?

Comment: @AK: эксперимент: возьмём [top 100 участников на ru.SO](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/609/year/ru-stackoverflow/2018-01-01?sort=reputationchange&page=2). Сколько по вашему мужчин/женщин? Считаете ли вы что эту цифру нужно поменять? Почему?

Comment: Интересно почитать, особенно, на фоне недавней темы о выпиливании приветственных фраз, типа "Добрый день!")

Comment: "особой недружелюбности к женщинам и национальным меньшинствам" - втф??? Первое - явный бред, мне всегда казалось, что к девушкам в IT сфере относятся наоборот наиболее дружелюбно из-за их малой концентрации в сообществе, особенно если они хотят профессионально расти. Второе - вообще вынос мозга, интересно как по посту можно определить национальность человека чтобы потом проявить к нему особую недружелюбность.

Comment: @yolosora, это не ко мне. Такова позиция руководства SO, выраженная в переведённой мной блогозаписи. Поэтому я и разместил здесь перевод, чтобы не удивляться, когда у нас начнутся массовые подвижки на эту тему. Кстати, на MetaSO [тоже крайне недоумевают на этот счёт](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366665/2553424).

Comment: @Arhad это и не было прямым вопросом, просто возмущение)

Comment: @jfs: Какая бы там ни была цифра — почему вдруг её должно хотеться поменять? [Вам же не хочется поменять процент негров среди жителей Магадана?]

Comment: @VladD это ж сейчас тренд, все эти крики про дайвёрсити и т.п.

Comment: @yolosora ну, например, смотрит на аватарку, видит индуса, и сразу предвзятое мнение.

Comment: @Suvitruf: Видит другую расу — это ещё полбеды. А если другой биологический вид? Кролик, например? Долой дискриминацию по отношению к семейству зайцеобразных!

Comment: @VladD есть у людей предвзятое мнение, если на аве аниме персонаж )

Comment: @Suvitruf: Когда мне надоест кролик, поставлю анимешную деффачку.

Comment: @VladD best waifu - Vlad waifu =D

Comment: @Suvitruf, например? К Yolosora отношение нейтральное.

Comment: @Suvitruf: (〃▽〃)

Comment: @Arhad да это же старая тема из разряда "если видишь на аве аниме персонажа, то делишь мнение на 3", которая, к сожалению, не на пустом месте выросла.

Comment: Кстати вот еще один тред с меты большого SO разделяющий мои возмущения :) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366937/is-stack-overflow-really-racist-sexist?cb=1

Comment: @yolosora "интересно как по посту можно определить национальность человека". Национальность довольно легко определить по аватару пользователя, если он добавил свою фотку, иногда и по имени тоже можно или по языку написания имени (к примеру, если человек на грузинском написал своё имя, то, скорее всего, он грузин). Но в целом с вашем позицией согласен. Дискриминация, уверен, и до это поста хорошо присекалась и не носила массовый характер.

Comment: Было бы интересно найти все вопросы, заданные представителями нацменьшинств, обезличить их, изменив имена и убрав аватарки, сбросить голоса, поднять и посмотреть изменится ли на них реакция.

Comment: Я согласен с постом, наконец-то авторы сообщества взялись за эту тему. Буллинг новичков и не только реально удручает. Конечно в америке это тема меньшинств, женщин, у нас в России другие темы, но тем не менее суть сообщения мне понравилась и считаю что полностью подходит к нам. Кроме того аплодисменты за желание добавить автоформатирование кода, уже давно про это пишу.

Comment: @VladD и это будет твоя вайфу...

Comment: Прошел тест - выявлен закоренелый расист :)

Comment: @Arhad я добавлю в пост disclaimer, если вы не против? Если против - откатите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @PashaPash, пожалуйста, добавляйте.

Comment: @PashaPash *целиком* -> *в целом*, пока не истёк период свежей правки.

Comment: @Arhad спасибо. но вообще - я оффлайне, так что подправляйте на свое усмотрение

Comment: Сам попытался добавить на английскую мету, закрыли(( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374957/stack-overflow-isn-t-very-welcoming-it-s-time-for-that-to-change

Comment: О какой дружелюбности может идти речь если в начале вопроса вырезается приветствие?

Comment: @VladD уже прошло больше 4 лет, кролик пропал, а девочка не появилась :(. На [держите](https://ru.myanimeshelf.com//eva2/upload/27faf5d689c4ae71dacfec303675273f/A.jpg). Она, кстати, немка

Comment: @Danis: Спасибо! Кролик таки ушёл, анимешная девочка, наверное, появится, если я сумею войти второй раз в ту же реку. За вашу спасибо, классная <3

Answer (score 33):

Выскажусь, как ветеран enSO и ruSO (а.к.а. Хэшкод):

Мне приходится время от времени буквально заставлять себя отвечать на вопросы юзеров - беда в том, что вопросы одни и те же... Ну невозможно изо дня в день (я бы даже сказал из года в год) отвечать на одни и те же вопросы - это очень трудно. Непроизвольно рождается агрессия, ирония, сарказм и т.д.

Именно по этой причине, я с Нового Года я практически перестал посещать сайт и отвечать на вопросы, раз в неделю зайдешь - посмотришь и все одно и то же. Лучше я буду молчать, чем рождать агрессию. Глядишь через полгода опять начну заходить  и начну отвечать на вопросы...

Понимаю, что такой подход рождает низкое качество ответов, что автоматически ведет к низкому качеству вопросов, но увы...

Если сформулировать то получается:

- опытным юзерам/экспертам здесь скучно
- новичкам здесь некомфортно.

**P.S.** *Чукча не писатель, чукча читатель*, это к тому, что я не претендую на рожание рецептов излечения, я лишь констатирую.

Comment: Вполне с вами согласен! Бесит, что часто поиски интересных и толковых вопросов занимают больше времени, чем написание достаточно больших ответов. И позиция очень конструктивная: лучше ничего не отвечать на низкосортный вопрос, чем слить негатив.

Comment: Интересно, администрация ресурса мониторит активность топовых пользователей? Будет какая-нибудь реакция, если после введения каких-нибудь новых правил вдруг уйдут самые активные отвечающие?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нет, не мониторит, администрация заинтересована в общем трафике, при мне уже многажды уходили супер топы - ничего не менялось. Позиция типа: ресурс крутой и нам пофигу до отдельных субъектов. В принципе позиция понятная и где-то обоснованная.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov А меня бесит :) выражение "слить негатив". Вы бы не могли выразиться более изящно?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev всегда есть естественная убыль активных отвечающих, даже если правила не меняются. Даже если администрация будет принимать решения только в пользу опытных и экспертов - они все равно со временем уйдут, а новички - не придут. Меньше всех новичков -> Меньше *вменяемых* новичков -> меньше всех вопросов -> меньше *хороших* вопросов -> старожилам скучно -> они от скуки начинают давить на новичков, еще больше уменьшая поток и начинают чаще уходить. Стагнация.

Comment: @PashaPash я как раз про неестественную убыль. И не постепенную, а массовую. Ведь толку от хороших вопросов будет мало, если некому будет давать хорошие ответы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ее очень тяжело отличить от естественной. И кроме того, естественная убыль у нас очень значительна. просто незаметна - участники пропадают без шума и без следа.

Comment: @PashaPash с этим как-то пытаются бороться?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev это естественная убыль, ее нельзя побороть, можно только компенсировать. Участнику надоело отвечать на вопросы - все, он исчез. Можно чуть-чуть снизить, например, расширением оффтопика - кодгольф и прочее. Но незначительно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev т.е. мы (сообщество + администрация) вынуждены сидеть и мыть тонны песка в поисках крупинок золота. Любой участник, который не помогает мыть, а высказывает ненависть к песку и массово выбрасывает его в реку - активно вредит процессу. Отсюда бинайс и прочее "угнетение".

Comment: @PashaPash возможно, эту естественную убыль можно было бы уменьшить. У спрашивающих есть сильный мотив задать вопрос - решение их личной проблемы, при этом от них не требуется каких-либо значимых усилий. В то время как отвечающие тратят своё личное время и силы, имея при этом куда более слабые мотивы к этому. Тем не менее, вектор усилий администрации направлен именно на спрашивающих, на сколько я вижу. Разве это не сбрасывание намытого обратно в реку?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Дело в том, что те,  кто недружелюбен к новичкам,  и основные отвечающие  - это две слабопересекающиеся группы. Чаще всего предупреждения о нарушении "будьте дружелюбными" получают пользователи с 1-5 тыс репутации (могу сделать более точную выборки).  Это те,  кто освоился на сайте,  но еще не понимают,  что хорошие вопросы просто так не появляются. И они начинают требовать "не несите нам песок", начинают поучать,  начинают придираться к словам в формулировка вопросов (вроде "можно ли сделать zzz" - "можно, разрешаю! ").

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev На сайте есть достаточно надежный механизм фильтрации вопросов. С защитой от выбрасывания золота через требование 5 голосов. А поучающие этот механизм обходят, и берут на себя право судить единолично. Это повышает шанс выбрасывает хороших новичков в мусорку, вместе с их будущим хорошими вопросами. Одна ошибка в оформлении,  одно слово,  или просто судящий не с той ноги встал - и все,  минус десяток будущих хороших вопросов.

Comment: @PashaPash это я понимаю. Даже адекватную критику бывает тяжело воспринимать, не то что подколы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev похоже,  придется оформлять отдельным постом с примерами и статистикой :) может быть поможет убрать ощущение давящего бинайса.

Comment: @PashaPash было бы интересно!

Comment: @Barmaley а я помню как вы мне помагали когда я жестко тупил в начале! Теперь даже виртуальные подзатыльники с ностальгией вспоминаются. Зря вы так.

Comment: @PashaPash, а что такое бинайс?

Comment: @PashaPash в ваших комментариях налицо по сути отрицание проблемы. Звучит примерно так: *не ну местах бывают перегибы, но в целом политика сайта правильная, все хорошо, есть механизмы бла-бла-бла*. Не буду особенно сильно спорить, просто приведу короткий аргумент, если бы не было проблемы то не было бы данного поста и такой жаркой дискуссии.

Comment: @Barmaley отрицание какой именно проблемы? Да,  на so (en/ru) вопросы интереснее за пару лет не стали. Да, одно и то же,  и старикам скучно (я тоже редко отвечаю). Скучно настолько,  что начали предлагать запретить новым пользователям задавать вопросы (чтобы не спрашивали одно и то же)  Да,  многие восприняли этот пост как попытку кого-то принудить к вежливости. Но проблему как-то осознать и решать. А сейчас активное ядро стариков решило,  что проблема в том,  что администрация просто хочет навязать слишком высокие стандарты вежливости.

Comment: @Barmaley т.е. тут некоторые считают, что вежливость требуется уж слишком излишняя,  нужно пожестче с новичками, чтобы те задавали только интересные вопросы, а не мусор,  как обычно. А администрация против, и принуждает быть излишне вежливыми. Это необоснованое принуждение на сленге  местного чата - бинайс.

Comment: Вот посмотрите ответ от Other. Почему он воспринял перевод поста про английский so (а там все жестче)  как личное обвинение непонятно в чем?

Comment: @PashaPash ну в таком случае я конечно же поддерживаю *бинайс*

Comment: @PashaPash оценочно SO генерирует прибыль в районе $100 mln в год. Если они направят 10% своих доходов на поддержание штанов старичков с рейтингом скажем от 20-50 тыс, то у старичков сразу же появится жесткая мотивация быть вежливыми :) Я думаю корень находится где-то здесь

Comment: *Ну невозможно изо дня в день (я бы даже сказал из года в год) отвечать на одни и те же вопросы - это очень трудно. Непроизвольно рождается агрессия, ирония, сарказм и т.д.* - воистину... И еще - не уверен, конечно, возможно, это просто накопление опыта - но полное ощущение, что чем дальше, тем вопросы становятся глупее и глупее...Ну, или политкорректности для - все проще и проще. Неинтереснее и неинтереснее. Нет интеллектуального вызова :(

Comment: @Barmaley это замена внутренней мотивации на внешнюю, и она невыгодна в долгосрочной перспективе. Достаточно перестать платить, или даже начать платить чуть меньше - и мотивация упадет даже ниже первоначального уровня. Кроме того, будет негативный эффект от "соцсоревнования" - новые отвечающие будут меньше участвовать в жизни сайта, т.к. "старички уже сняли все сливки, без шансов их догнать". Ну и стандартная проблема - будут работать на KPI, а не от души. Как-то был модером на QA, где администраторам спускали KPI по "отвеченным вопросам" - ничего хорошего не получилось.

Answer (score 19):

Как я понял этот пост (поправьте меня, если не прав):
Мы — хороший сайт, но создаётся впечатление недружелюбного, тут новичков ехидно тыкает за незнание правил некая "илитарная" группа.
Хватит это терпеть!
Мы ужесточаем правила дружелюбия и толерантности, а-ля: будь вежливым, сука!

---

Я не против новичков, ведь иначе меня бы тут не было как более-менее активного участника.
Из этого, как мне кажется, можно сделать вывод: не старички недостаточно вежливы (да, бывает, не спорю, но в основном), а новички недостаточно обучены перед своим первым вопросом.
Как это выглядит - регистрируешься (а иногда вообще аноним), тебе *предлагают* ознакомится с правилами, которые больше справка, нежели краткий гайд по реально нужным новичку правилам и, без всякой модерации, пишут вопрос.

---

Тут либо муштровать старичков до умиротворения уровень Будда, либо попытаться сделать так, чтобы новички действительно читали правила, запоминали оттуда хоть чуть-чуть и потом уже вопрошали.
И даже не знаю что более реализуемо.

Comment: Это перевод,  в нем описано отношение прежде всего к enSO. высказывать все подряд стоит автору оригинала :)

Comment: @PashaPash, я оригинал видел раньше перевода, но раз перевели, то нас он тоже касается.

Comment: Касается в том плане,  что это часть правил,  которые сверху пришли. Но скорее это посыл быть добрее на enSO,  чтобы стало как на ruSO сейчас :) а то тут недавно на мете пробегало "в английском уже бы заминусовали и послали,  а мы тут слишком добрые"

Comment: Тогда стоит сделать приписку на этот счёт, а то в данном виде воспринимаешь как и для себя посыл.

Comment: Это уже вопрос к автору или к переводчику. Но даже с такой поправкой - я не понимаю, как этот пост можно было понять как "есть Илитарная группа и она тыкает". Ничего такого там и близко нет.  Даже если как-то проецировать на ruSO - у нас элитарные и тыкающие - это две непересекающиеся группы :)

Comment: @PashaPash, да полните, Вы поняли что я имел ввиду.

Comment: Ес-но понял. Но оригинале речь шла явно не об этом. Вы же сами попросили в ответе поправить,  если вы не правы. Вот я и поправляю. Вы не правы,  в оригинале вообще не о том (или не совсем о том)

Comment: @PashaPash, это так. Но Вы не поправили, а просто сказали: "Не так понял". Скажите как правильней.

Comment: Скажу как только доберусь до стационарного компа. А то телефон модератора неудобен

Comment: @PashaPash, купите новый :) Жду.

Comment: @PashaPash, Вы не забыли объяснить что к чему?

Comment: не забыл. просто не успеваю - пытаюсь делать вещи по приоритету :(

Comment: Дмитрий, не надо исправлять намеренные эрративы

Comment: @PavelMayorov как хотите, но режет же глаз, невозможно...)

Comment: @Dmitry, "илита" - это мем, интернет-сленг. Для придания саркастичности специально пишется с И. Взял в кавычки, может не так сильно будет резать)

Answer (score 15):

Уж не знаю, кому тут нужно мое мнение, но я все таки его выскажу) Лично я не могу сказать, что SO так уж недружелюбен (в особенности - ru.SO).

---

Я постоянно вижу, как более опытные пользователи помогают ещё новичкам править не совсем корректно поставленные вопросы. Я постоянно вижу, как даже достаточно глупые и, казалось бы, очевидные вопросы таки получают весьма хорошие ответы. Я постоянно вижу, как опытные и не очень участники безо всякой агрессии и «снисходительного тона» разъясняют вопрошавшим элементарные истины. Это ли все не показатель той самой *дружелюбности*?

---

Да, конечно, есть некоторые моменты, которые мне не совсем понятны (как человеку): к примеру, уже не один раз поднимавшийся вопрос о том, нужны ли сообществу *комментарии с благодарностями*. С точки зрения интеллектуального наполнения SO, конечно, они не несут ничего, но многие люди (и я в том числе) просто не могут не поблагодарить человека, который хоть секунду своего времени и хоть йоту своих знаний потратил на помощь мне (и любому, кто столкнётся с аналогичной проблемой в будущем). Так что ситуации, когда в ответ на своё «спасибо» ты получаешь нечто вроде: «У нас тут такие комментарии неуместны», действительно могут заставить чувствовать себя не в своей тарелке)

---

Помимо этого мне так же не совсем ясен (опять же, как человеку, а не как какому-никакому члену комьюнити) тот факт, что у нас запрещены вопросы, где ответы базируются на *личном мнении* участников. Да, это не вписывается в формат строгой базы знаний. Да, у каждого (в рамках такого гипотетического вопроса) был свой путь в решении такового. Но в этом, как мне кажется, и есть сама ценность - послушать, как множество хороших программистов излагают свои точки зрения на поставленный вопрос. Отсутствие такого формата, как мне кажется, так же немного порой добавляет привкуса «*бездушности*» происходящего ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

---

Однако на «*недружелюбность*» SO, как я считаю, большей частью все таки жалуются именно те «*новички*», которые, совершенно не удосужившись прочитать правила сообщества, задают непонятные, странные и неверно отформатированные вопросы. Самое интересное, даже на них на деле не выливается никакой агрессии. Думаю, весьма забавный тому пример -  [сей вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/821649/248572). Гражданин вообще не понял, что тут и зачем происходит. Увидел, что его любимый Minecraft выдаёт ошибку со словами «**Java**», и полез сюда. И единственное, куда его послали - на ответы mail_ru. Все по-доброму посмеялись и разошлись.

---

Собственно, хотелось бы все же отрезюмировать свою позицию из всего, что было сказано выше: как кажется мне, SO (как и ru.SO) развивается в правильном направлении. В конечном счете, мы сидим не просто на каком-то форуме, мы формируем базу знаний, как бы то не звучало масштабно, но в том числе и для многих будущих поколений. Подумайте сами: разве можно допускать, чтобы труды таких людей, как [Джон Скит](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (касательно SO), [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) (касательно ru.SO) и многих других, в итоге оказались погребены под тоннами непонятных вопросов или вопросов рода «помогите сделать лабу» лишь по той причине, что мы дружелюбны ко всем и всему? Нужно чувствовать границу. Нельзя терять человечности, но и нельзя допускать «замутнения» нашей с вами базы знаний. Если человек хочет стать частью комьюнити - он все таки должен быть знаком с его правилами. Если же он обижается, когда ему мягко указывают на его ими полное пренебрежение - то это уже не проблемы комьюнити ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Начало хорошее, конец (про базу знаний) неверный. Без обилия вопросов (а это значит, что задающий вопрос должен чувствовать себя *комфортно*) вообще никакой базы не будет.

Comment: @avp с этим я совершенно согласен. Только одно: а как обеспечить этот самый комфорт? Тут два пути: либо убрать любые сдерживающие факторы, чтобы себя комфортно чувствовал абсолютно каждый вопрошающий, либо же все таки заставить новоприбывших знакомиться с этими самыми рамками, которые обеспечивают чистоту и порядок в комьюнити, дабы они сами регулировали себя, что не так уж и трудно. Лично я считаю, что комфорт необходимо обеспечивать именно за счёт детального ознакомления пользователей с основными правилами комьюнити, ведь знающий человек как раз и будет ощущать себя в комфортабельной среде

Comment: Вот из-за того, что у многих участников такие же мысли (о правилах и что все их должны учить) и возникают кризисы, в результате которых появляются подобные статьи (данный вопрос на Мете). Мне кажется, решение должно быть вообще в другой плоскости. Сайт делится на 3 части. 1) То, что сейчас с облегченными правилами. 2) То что сейчас для потенциально обидчивых. 3) Пресловутая база знаний (туда отправляются отборные вопросы и хорошие ответы на них, уже отредактированные и без лишних комментариев)

Comment: @avp даёшь деление по кастам на SO :D

Comment: @Suvitruf, на самом деле не вижу в этом ничего плохого. Конечно, при условии, что можно принадлежать более чем к одной и свободно их менять.

Comment: @avp Идея с кастами правда достаточно интересная, но не стоит забывать, что в рамках Stack Exchange существуют не только SO и ru.SO. Помножьте каждое идейное ответвление на 3. Мы же просто утонем в таком количестве ветвящихся сайтов... Да и те самые новички и/или обижающиеся, для коих вы предполагаете все это сделать, сами же в этой системе и запутаются хД

Comment: @Kir_Antipov,  тогда вы обречены остаться в довольно однообразной компании

Comment: @avp вы так говорите, будто чтение правил и следование их элементарным основам - настолько сложная вещь, что доступна только каким-то полубогам минимум...

Comment: Вы не поняли. Чтение правил и следование *всем им* это не одно и то же.

Comment: @avp нет, это прекрасно понятно. Да и я написал не «всем им», а все же «элементарным основам». И, если я вас правильно понял, вы подразумеваете, что человек, прочитавший правила, может их осознанно нарушать? Если да, то зачем комьюнити такой человек?

Comment: Такую комьюнити я и называю однообразной. Вы уверены, что сами  всегда хотите быть как все?

Comment: @avp у нас диалог уже куда-то в иное русло уплывает) Говорили о дружелюбности на нашей платформе, а дошли уже до: «Нужны ли нам эти правила?» хД

Comment: Это все взаимосвязано. Смотрите, вы же сами пишете -- *`"Помимо этого мне так же не совсем ясен (опять же, как человеку, а не как какому-никакому члену комьюнити) тот факт, что у нас запрещены вопросы, где ответы базируются на личном мнении участников"`*. Это очевидный пример *недружелюбных* (по отношению к части участников) правил. Вот так обсуждение дружелюбия сайта сводится к обсуждению правил.

Comment: Как я вижу это. Дружелюбие и недружелюбие друг друга не отрицают. Дело в том что по одним вопросам одни люди могут себя вести дружелюбно и в одних ситуациях. Тогда как другие  в других ситуациях могут себя вести не дружелюбно, или просто другие люди. Конечно у нас много дружелюбия. А вот сообщение автора я понял как желание поправить недружелюбные моменты.

Answer (score 15):

Я тут посмотрел...
Я зарегистрировался на сайте примерно в ноябре 2015 года - похоже, 19.11.2015.

Первый вопрос я задал 10.02.2016 года.

Т.е. я **три месяца** просто смотрел, как это все работает, какие вопросы можно задавать, какие не стоит... какие ответы вызывают одобрение, какие нет. И только после этого начал активную деятельность :)

Право слово, когда человек регистрируется на сайте только для того, чтобы, не удосужившись не то чтоб посмотреть его содержимое и поискать интересующую информацию - просто прочесть FAQ - тут же начинает строчить (по сути) вопросы "*Вот такая задача, я в программировании ни фига не понимаю, так что быстренько сделали мне на шару...*" или "*у меня какая-то фигня, но код я вам не покажу, и какая фигня, тоже не скажу - но эти тупые разработчики компиляторов явно пишут свои компиляторы со страшными ошибками, вот я и нарвался на очередную!*" или "*вот такая задница случилась! да, на сайте эта проблема в разных вариациях встречалась раз 20-30-40, но я вам что, мистер Гугль, чтоб искать? ответите еще раз, руки не отвалятся и клавиатуру не разобьете...*"...

Или в варианте (вчера, кажется) - мол, посмотрите, у вас тут проблема в том, что переменная локально объявлена в цикле `for`, а обращение к ней после - недовольный комментарий от автора вопроса "я убрала слово for, ничего не поменялось!" - т.е. человек просто не думая что-то делает, лишь бы скомпилировалось... понятно, что после этого он будет засыпать тупыми вопросами "а чего оно скомпилировалось, но не делает, что надо?"...

Так вот, очень, *очень*, **ОЧЕНЬ** трудно оставаться при этом дружелюбным и взаимовежливым...

Comment: Всё верно. И всё более актуально с каждым днём...

Answer (score 8):

Не знаю как там на Западе, но у бо́льшей части мужского населения РуНета сильнейший *синдром белого рыцаря*. Я знаю на ruSO пользователей, которые его даже умудряются эксплуатировать, заводя себе виртуалов женского пола. И пока учётку с мужским именем и аватаркой за глупые вопросы и задания сливают, те же самые вопросы под учёткой с женским именем и аватаркой получают плюсы и помощь.

Comment: Занятно, как это голословное утверждение коррелирует с тем, что бо́льшая часть мужского IT населения в России предвзяты не в лучшую сторону к женщинам в IT?

Comment: @Suvitruf По-разному бывает. Мне кажется, чаще, наоборот предвязаты в лучшую сторону. И помогут, если что, и восхитятся сочетанию красоты и ума. Ещё чаще, могут относится нейтрально, также как и к представителям своего пола.

Comment: @Suvitruf возможно мне повезло с окружением, но я никогда не замечал предвзятого отношения к сотрудницам женского пола ни в одной из компаний, в которой работал. Ну, если не считать предвзятостью то, что девочек-админов не заставляли таскать UPS'ы и не требовали от них 35-часовых авралов, а девочки-программисты легко могли оправдать любые проступки физиологическими проблемами, могли отпроситься пораньше, мотивируя детьми, и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Я вот наоборот почти везде замечаю, что к женщинам-программистам предвзято относятся. И это не только в RU. Когда я был в USA, там было тоже самое. "Женщина-программист? Ха-ха", "Женщина - фаундер стартапа? Ха-ха".

Comment: @Suvitruf это часть гендерного стереотипа (и гендера самого по себе, в смысле "поведения человека на основании того, чего он него ждет общество, а не основании пола". Гендер в разных странах чуть-чуть отличается, и сильно меняется со временем. Например, на факультете, где я учился, в мой год на потоке было 6 девушек (из 90 человек). А за 20 лет до этого - 4 парня на 90 человек.

Comment: @Suvitruf сильный перекос в сторону мужчин в естественных науках сейчас создается примерно в 5-6 классе, учителями и родителями. Если начать активно советовать девочкам математику, а парням - рисование - перекос поменяется.

Comment: @PashaPash вы куда-то не в ту степь пошли. Моя изначальная претензия была к "бо́льшей части мужского" и "белым рыцарям" )

Comment: @Suvitruf да, но это тоже следствие разделения и численного перевеса. те же 30 лет назад в математических вузах наверняка было полно девушек, желающих помочь с домашкой редким парням :)

Comment: @Suvitruf, вы оба с Горностаевым правы. Да, относятся не как к равным себе. И поэтому не гнобят, а помогают с большим вниманием, чем парням.

Comment: @Suvitruf если девушка в IT паразитирует косвенно аргументируя своим полом или опираясь на него, то это вызывает разумную негативную реакцию. Если девушка вкалывает и обращается за помощью как специалист к специалистам - это только порадует любого.

Comment: Странный ответ, смахивает на какую-то обидку и сексисзм! Мне как представительнице женского пола не комфортно на ruSo как раз из-за поднятия, временами, таких тем! 
И негатив, минусование моих многих вопросов\ответов одним неким (к счастью уже заблокированым )  типом было связано отчасти из-за пола!

Comment: с тех пор сижу под нейтральным hamster чтобы никого не смущать и ненароком не накрутить голоса за счет своего пола (как вы утверждаете), который на ruSo после многих дискуссий решили не переводить (участниЦА).

Comment: @HamSter видимо, у нас с вами очень разный культурный код, так как я не представляю, как можно увидеть _обидку_ в тексте моего ответа. А некомфортную тему поднял Jay Hanlon.

Comment: @HamSter прошу заметить, я не утверждаю, что нет глупых мужчин, рассказывающих шутки про морских свинок. Просто мой опыт подсказывает мне, что таких в РуНете не больше, чем _белых рыцарей_.

Comment: "я не представляю, как можно увидеть обидку в тексте моего ответа"  извините) , показалось. Пожалуй соглашусь, что тема интересная, но в плане разделения на м\ж . Частные случаи, когда мужчины полагают, что женщине не место в программировании и другая сторона, вот, когда наоборот мужчины поощряют женский пол своим вниманием. )

Comment: @HamSter Мои симпатии на Вашей стороне. Это, наверное, сексизм.

Comment: И все побежали создавать себе учетки женского пола)))))) Шучу. Сексизм не сексизм, а некоторые культурно-психологические особенности все равно проступают, не удивительно что есть те кто  находит им вполне практическое применение.

Comment: @Pavel все, кроме жертв советского сексистского воспитания, которое не позволяло девочек как обижать, так и прикидываться ими )

Answer (score 8):

Я давно хотел высказать пару мыслей, и мне кажется, самое время.

Во-первых, по поводу "SO уже не тот". Я думаю, многие читали статью [Куда катится мир?](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%3F) на Лурке, а кто не читал, тому стоит почитать. Хотя бы раздел "Боян". Там приводятся примеры стенаний на тему "Молодежь уже не та" возрастом более 3000 лет (ссылка на первоисточник есть, я по ней ходил, проверял, источник достаточно качественный). На протяжении всей человеческой истории этот поток жалоб не прекращался. Так что если кто-то просто жалуется, что раньше было хорошо, а теперь плохо, это не значит ровным счетом ничего. Нужны какие-то более надежные, проверяемые и измеряемые показатели.

Во-вторых, по поводу качества аудитории с обоих концов (и спрашивающих, и отвечающих). Совершенно очевидная вещь, про которую все забывают, - информация в интернете почти не пропадает. Конечно, нельзя быть уверенным, что любая случайно выбранная ссылка проживет хотя бы год. Но точно можно быть увереренным, что ответ на вопрос "как получить список всех таблиц в Oracle" или "синтаксис цикла for в java" найти можно будет за несколько секунд всегда, пока живы поисковики. Отсюда следует печальный вывод, что все, кто умеет гуглить - гуглят, а не приходят с вопросами на SO. Качество поисковиков растет, качество контента растет. Все более сложные вопросы удается нагуглить. Что делать? Смириться с тем, что самые толковые и смышленые новички, с кем приятнее было бы общаться, будут спрашивать у гугла, а не на SO. Естественно, отвечающим не нравится, что до SO доходят самые ленивые.

В-третьих, по поводу расовой дискриминации. Расскажу, как рассовой дискриминацией занимался я. Некоторое время назад на enSO было нашествие (по крайней мере, мне казалось, что одно время была волна, а теперь она пошла на спад) довольно неграмотных новичков, которые обладали рядом признаков:

- ужасный английский, на грани полного отсутствия смысла текстов
- полная техническая неграмотность и неспособность понять, а что же вообще происходит
- полное отсутствие ответов на уточняющие вопросы в комментариях
- естественно, при ответе - ни тебе спасибо, ни плюс нажать, ни ответ принять
- и как правило - имя, похожее на китайское, индийское или арабское.

Естественно, через какое-то время я просто перестал открывать и читать вопросы (а уж тем более отвечать), если имя автора каким-либо образом напоминало о перечисленных национальностях. Дискриминация? Она самая, во весь рост. Угрызения совести? "Я нормально ем, и спокойно сплю" (с) Вася Обломов.

В-четвертых, по поводу теста на скрытую предвзятость. Многие наверное знают биолога Александра Маркова, он известный популяризатор науки. Однажды он тоже прошел тест на предвзятость, видимо, аналогичный данному (тот же самый или нет, не знаю), о чем о рассказал у себя в блоге. Тест показал, что да, господин Марков дискриминирует женщин и чернокожих. Разработчики теста оставили форму обратной связи. Те, кто не согласен с вердиктом, могли описать принцип, по которому они отвечали на вопросы. Вопросы в тесте были, по словам Маркова, такого рода: вы едете на машине, дорогу перебегает человек, вы можете сбить его, а можете свернуть на обочину с риском сбить кого-то на обочине. В общем, моральный выбор без однозначно правильного ответа. Ну и естественно, там были указаны характеристики участников: кто из них женщина, кто старик, кто ребенок, кто негр, кто белый богатый мужчина. Марков сказал, что его принцип ответов на вопросы был следующий: если вопрос касался ситуации как выше (кто-то перебегает дорогу), то его принцип - однозначно не должен страдать тот, кто не виноват. То есть если пешеход нарушает правила и перебегает дорогу перед автомобилем, пусть лучше пострадает он, а не невиновный пешеход на обочине. У меня нет оснований не верить Маркову. Он собаку съел на популяризации науки и борьбе с суевериями и стереотипами. И, если он действительно придерживался описанных принципов, то скорее всего сами разработчики тестов неявно дискриминировали женщин, негров и представителей прочих "меньшинств", "назначая" их нарушителями ПДД в тестовых ситуациях.

Честно скажу, тесты я не проходил (ни тот, на который ссылался Марков, ни этот). Но не больно-то и хочется, если честно.

Comment: Я тоже проходил тот тест. Там разработчики никого не дискриминируют, ситуации полностью случайны. Но проблема - в том что возможных "дискриминаций" *больше чем вопросов в тесте*! В итоге независимо от ваших ответов система хоть что-нибудь да найдет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov "Разработчики никого не дискриминируют, это система такая." - замечательно.

Comment: @Igor что именно замечательно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Система возникла сама, без участия разработчиков? (Skynet became self-aware.)

Comment: @Igor но система тоже никого не дискриминирует.

Comment: Про Маркова интересно было послушать.

Comment: А я проходил те, что предложили. И, разумеется, я не люблю США, геев, чёрных и женщин (последнее вообще вопиюще!). Что-то не верю, зная себя и своё отношение к этим вопросам. P. S. Качество изображений довольно плохое, я не столько выбирал ответ, сколько пытался рассмотреть что там. Думаю на результат повлияло.

Comment: Тоже проходил тесты по ссылке, дико вынесла мозг концепция, нужно кликнуть 50 раз влево где мужчины и карьера и вправо где женщины и семья, потом проводится ротация на мужчина-семья и женщина-карьера, чисто на уровне механической памяти запрограммировал себя на лево-право и  несколько раз ошибся -> слегка сексист :)

Comment: Ну так а вас всё хорошо: вы прошли мимо некачественных постов, а кто-то мог взять и написать оскорбительные комментарии автору. Этим людям и адресована статья. И, возможно, даже не зря.

Answer (score 8):

Мой взгляд со стороны тех кто по большей части спрашивает, может чем-то будет полезен.

Может русскоязычная часть SO и не идеальна, но знаете, если сравнивать  c англоязычной его частью, мы явно далеко впереди в смысле товарищеского отношения к чужим ошибкам. По моему опыту, когда вопрос сильно горит и я дублирую его на анлоязычной и русскоязычной частях SO, тут минус крайне редкое явление, в крайнем случае намекнут что вопрос не очень, уточнив: переформулируй, уточни и тд, а на англоязычном SO без раберательств сразу получаю пару минусов за то же самое.

Comment: Просто тут пока ... (определение выберите сами), минусующих *вопросы* меньше

Comment: За минус надо платить! А у нас менталитет немного еврейский в этом деле :)

Comment: @Other за минус ответа нужно платить, а вопрос можно минусовать бесплатно.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, ну тогда держись вопросы! :)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev интересная мысль, может надо просто за минусование вопроса тоже репу снимать. Хочешь сказать что вопрос на столько плох? - Проголосуй репой, а если репы жалко на это, можоет он и не так уж плох..? В этом что-то есть...

Comment: @Pavel лучше снимать репу за плюсование вопроса. А то я регулярно вижу в плюсах однозначно плохие вопросы.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev 0_о уж очень сурово... Так не какой репы не хватит.

Comment: @Pavel если репы жалко, может он не так уж и хорош? ;)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev ))) Остроумно, мне понравилось!;))) Но с другой стороны плюсы, минусы и это вот все  для развития сообщества, а то может получиться борьба за некую абстрактную справедливость ради нее самой. И вместо улучшения качества контента и взаимоотношений участников получится SOКомЗапрет, чуть что сразу по шапке...

Comment: @Pavel на сколько я понимаю, всё бурление вокруг темы этого вопроса как раз и обусловлено тем, что многие видят в этом затягивание гаек и организации SOКомЗапрета.

Answer (score 7):

Я всё-таки не удержался и решил написать ответ, т.к. меня довольно сильно раздражает вся эта тема с be-nice. Нет, грубить другим и оскорблять - это плохо, но почему-то некоторые очень сильно на be-nice зациклены.

Я вообще изначально хотел пройтись по оригинальной статье, написать о том, что автор оной - расист, сексист и позволяет себе шутеечки, но при этом другим советуют не отпускать шуточки, но не буду, так как про это уже [написал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7242/15479) товарищ Igor.

Вот только, к сожалению, прочитать его ответ большинство людей не смогут, так как ответ был удалён из-за нарушения "правила дружелюбия на ресурсе".

Это я к чему. Да, собственно, к тому самому.

Comment: Мне суета вокруг be-nice на SO временами напоминает историю с планетой Миранда в чудесном фильме "Миссия Серенити".

Comment: @Suvitruf Я писал свой ответ в расчете на нескольких человек (включая Вас) - и они его прочитали, судя по голосам. Считаю статью Хенлона, во-первых, ханжеской, а во-вторых, оскорбительной для целевой аудитории, которую он считает дурачками, не способными заметить это ханжество. Хотелось бы посмотреть, как "Дух сообщества" удалит хенлоновскую статью "как спам или оскорбление". Это был бы номер!

Answer (score 7):

я как раз из тех самых новичков и хочу сказать пару слов по теме.

Первое - SO по моим первым ощущениям достаточно дружелюбный сайт. Он конечно не идеален, но по сравнению с другими все-таки лучше. Здесь есть модерация и есть желание это обсуждать и совершенствовать.

Далее, насчет правил. Их наличие конечно хорошо, но все прекрасно знают, что их не читают, потому как некогда, они длинные и даже если их прочитать, то все равно не запомнишь. Но они нужны, поэтому надо найти какие-то способы, чтобы с ними ознакамливаться. Хорошая идея тур по правилам. А еще было бы неплохо, чтобы на страницах появлялись выдержки из правил, примерно как рекламные объявления.

Насчет повторяющихся вопросов - да, они есть и мне сдается они будут всегда. От этого похоже никуда не деться. Я могу понять постоянных посетителей, которым надоедает отвечать на одно и то же, но с другой стороны все через это проходили. Поэтому наверное надо найти какой-то формат работы с такими вопросами. Может быть модераторы или сами посетители, могли бы давать ссылки на уже имеющиеся темы, где эти вопросы обсуждались. Знаю, что есть автоматические ссылки такого типа, но они почему-то недостаточно работают. Не знаю почему, вроде бы одно и то же, но когда тебе напишут в теме, оно как-то воспринимается иначе.

Ну и конечно, хотелось бы, чтобы все-таки на вопросы отвечали, а не посылали в Гугл. Другое дело, что если в двух словах не объяснить, тогда вполне нормально воспринимается если об этом скажут и дадут ссылку, где можно более подробно посмотреть. Причем тут такой супертонкий момент, что если просто дадут ссылку, то это воспринимается напряженно, типа тебя носом тыкают, а если добавят пару нормальных слов, типа "не смогу все пересказать, лучше самому посмотреть", тогда оно воспринимается по-дружески.

Даже если ответа нет, то очень поддерживает типа - ты знаешь, твой вопрос непонятен, попробуй сформулировать по-другому. Или если напишут - знаешь, такой вопрос уже несколько/много раз задавали, поищи по такому-то ключевому слову, то это тоже воспринимается нормально.

В общем, вопрос в основном в конкретных формулировках. Одно и то же можно сказать по-разному.

Answer (score 6):

Хотел бы поделиться своим мнением по этому поводу.

Как на enSO, так и у нас мне никогда (везение и модерация, конечно, но не только они) не доводилось видеть какую-либо дискриминацию новичков. Максимум — подколы, пусть и обидные порой, но и те очень редко.

Да и сам я, честно говоря, на репу при голосовании/тревоге/ответе смотрю чисто ради интереса и в последнюю  очередь. На первом месте — контент. Впрочем, опытный пользователь редко (хотя бывает) задаст вопрос вне правил.
Улучшение вопроса — дело меня, как участника сообщества.

Как уже отметили, основная проблема заключается в незнании новичками правил. Что делать, ясно слабо. Попробовать доработать справку, сделать подсказки при написании первого вопроса/ответа. Впрочем, читать человека насильно не заставишь, но привлечь внимание можно. Предложить посмотреть хорошие вопросы (с высокой оценкой), плохие (с низкой оценкой).

Итого: мы либо улучшаем справку, либо смиряемся и "вежливием".