# Искусство гуглить и дубликаты, или почему нас минусуют

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы, дубликаты

[Дискуссии о дружелюбности SO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7219/stackoverflow-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C/7251?noredirect=1#comment29691_7251) породили мысль о вопросах-дубликатах, которыми я и сам **невольно** грешу время от времени. В процессе обсуждения в указаной выше теме один из старейших ветеранов даже выразился в том духе, что из за них ему вообще не хочется заходить на SO. Меня это как-то задело. И породило у меня мысль, которой я решил поделиться, чтобы узнать мнение сообщества (помидорами попрошу не кидаться).

В чем причина дубликатов? В том, что навык гугления ниже минимально необходимого. Искал как умел, не нашел, пошел на SO. Если бы нашел, то и проблемы нет; в конце концов, оформление вопроса занимает куда как больше времени, чем составление хорошего запроса в гугл. Значит что? Значит человек просто **не умеет это делать**, он же себе не враг — тратить время, чтобы минусы собирать.

Значит надо выделить навыки гугления в отдельную тему. Поиск гугл не шутка юмора, а серьезный инструмент, которым надо уметь пользоваться. Не все умеют. И здравый смысл, как впрочем и интуиция, подсказывают, что если помочь людям улучшить их навыки гугления, то многие проблемы с качеством вопросов уменьшат свой масштаб. Выходит, что гугл это единственный навигатор по SO для ищущего ответ, и другого навигатора у нас просто нет.

Как вы думаете, как можно повлиять на ситуацию? Нужен ли гайд "Как правильно гуглить" в какой-то форме, от кого-то кто **действительно умеет** это делать, и внедрять его в справку? Может какие-нибудь небольшие статьи-заметки у наших уважаемых ветеранов попросить иногда выпускать, типо как я гуглил этот тяжелый случай, или 3 признака плохого запроса?..

Или что-то еще, я не знаю, но эта тема уже просто как заноза, давайте что-нибудь придумаем.

Comment: *"Значит человек просто **не умеет это делать**, он же не враг себе тратить время что-бы минусы собирать"* -- только здесь сделано три довольно опасных предположения: (1) он пытался искать и не нашёл, (2) на составление вопроса потрачено существенное время, (3) его заботят минусы. Но в научных целях рассмотрим подмножество вопросов, для которых они выполняются :)

Comment: @D-side Прямо не в бровь, а в глаз! Почему не в ответы?

Comment: @AK потому что... последнее предложение в комментарии.

Comment: [нам **нравятся** некоторые дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Не нужно минусовать дубликаты! Нужно минусовать плохие вопросы. Хорошему дубликату можно ставить плюс и закрывать.

Comment: @D-side я вас не понял, почему вы считаете что предположение о том, что большинство пользователей относятся к SO добросовесно бережно, - это опасное предположение? Что же в нем по вашему опасного, и для кого? А то мне кажется, как будто я запутался, пытаясь вникнуть в вашу мысль.

Comment: @Pavel потому что оно имеет далеко ненулевую вероятность не выполняться. Вопрос выглядит так, будто решение этой проблемы решит проблему дубликатов напрочь. Но это не так. Но решить её даже частично – тоже дело.

Comment: @D-side а... ну если под таким углом, то я с вами полностю согласен. Я и не имел в виду понацею, в духе - мы сделаем что-то и все проблемы исчезнут. Начать с малого, и постепенно улучшать. А то что какой-то процент не вполне добросовесных пользователей существует - это конечно, но не будем же мы теперь только на них и ориентироваться... К стати, а как вы гуглите? Не поделитесь приемами в ответе?

Comment: @Pavel ну, делиться на "Stack Overflow на **русском**" советом "гуглите на **английском**" немножко нечестно, я считаю :D

Comment: @D-side да понимаю, но я имел в виду не совсем это. Скорее процедура составления запроса. Принципы вероятно одини и те же вне зависимости от языка. Хорошо когда можно просто ввести стектрейс в гугл и сразу получить ответ, а если важен контекст который может быть и не простым, а запрос должен быть коротким...

Comment: Отличная идея! Кстати знаю что на яндексе проводились раньше даже соревнованию по скорости поиска... Можно и на SO такие соревнования проводить ))

Comment: Правда минус в том, что гайды мало кто читает. Я например очень редко читаю. Но даже краткие справки и банеры думаю многие пропускают, так как в интернете сейчас тонны часто пустой иноформации, например правила общения на форуме... форумов десятки тысяч какой смысл на каждом форуме читать эти правила. Или например лицензионные соглашения длинной в десятки или сотни страниц, по идее читать нужно, но очень неразумно с точки зрения своего времени.

Comment: Искусство гуглить требуется редко. На много чаще достаточно просто скопировать ошибку в строку поиска или написать простое вопросительное предложение типа "Как парсить JSON на Python". Иногда хватит даже элементарного перечисления ключевых слов - "python json".

Answer (score 7):

> Нужен ли гайд "Как правильно гуглить" в какой-то форме, от кого-то кто
>   действительно умеет это делать, и внедрять его в справку?

Сначала нужно научиться определять кто умеет гуглить.

Помните Кубок Яндекса по поиску в интернет? Нужно устроить открытое соревнование по поиску (отдельно в поисковике; отдельно по enSo; отдельно по ruSO) и, сделав упор не на быстроте, а на тщательном логировании действий и объяснении шагов, выявлять типичные паттерны.

Там-то как раз и взлетят очевидные для многих вещи:

- что знание одного ЯП помогает в новой области (знаешь sqrt в одном языке – сначала проверь, а не названа ли она и в другом языке так же)
- что хорошо помогает изучение литературы (можно '[AngleSharp] make get request', но для POST намного лучше заменить на '[AngleSharp] submit form')
- что вообще хорошо знать английский (я лично вижу огромную разницу в паттернах гугления у своих коллег, кто знает и кто не знает английский)
- что знание некоторых ключевых принципов многократно возмещает незнание множества казалось бы разных фактов

---

Кроме того, нужно будет предварительно как-то обсудить, что делать с вопросами, которые плохо поддаются поиску. Скажем, кто-то предлагает конкретный JSON, который нужно распарсить при помощи JSON.Net. В текущей ситуации гораздо проще очередному страдальцу <s>дать рыбу</s> написать его конкретный кейс, чем пытаться вытащить более-менее подходящий пример (а они наверняка есть) – потому что просматривать придётся все вопросы по метке, а сузить словами вряд ли получится. Ну или надо написать большой гайд по десериализации, в котором рассмотреть все примеры и безжалостно закрывать на эталонный дубликат.

Или – пример на [десериализацию в Dictionary](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/829895/213987).

---

Ну и в целом о гайде. Гайд конечно прочитают (кто их вообще читает?) от силы 10% – но всё равно гайд по поиску мне кажется очень хорошей идеей. Я во время парного программирования обожаю смотреть кто как гуглит, когда ему не хватает линкупадовских скетчей. Но я бы к гайду хотел подойти именно разглядывая большое количество примеров, а не путём составления общих рекомендаций. И вписать эти примеры в гайд.

Comment: @A K спасибо за поддержку. Устраивать конкурсы это в иделе, но в нашем положении может быть уж очень фундаментально. Я думаю практически любой кто имеет больше 5К репы на SO умеет это делать, конечно есть те кто решит задачу особо изысканным способом, быстрее, умнее, красивее... но для новичков будет прорывом даже избежание очевидных ошибок. Да по поводу того что гайды мало кто читает это вы верно подметили. Но само его существование по краиней мере дает человеку шанс исправится. Я бы и сам в такой гайд с удовольствием углубулся...

Comment: Угу... Есть избитая истина, что "чтобы правильно задать вопрос, надо знать бОльшую часть ответа". К составлению правильного запроса в поисковике она имеет самое прямое отношение, и большинство вопрошающих, увы... но даже если смягчить эту истину до варианта "чтобы правильно задать вопрос, надо прилично разбираться в предметной области вопроса", то особо лучше не становится. А с учётом этого составление гайда, как мне кажется, превратится в "работу для себя". Ну или "для своих". Хотя... почему бы и нет?

Answer (score 2):

Не нужны подобные гайды, так как на текущий 2019 год проблем с дубликатами нет: вопросы-дубликаты поощряются сообществом. При этом чем проще [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1059713/256824), тем его ценность выше.

Забудьте, что когда-то данный сайт был задуман как база знаний. В данный момент важно *быстрее написать* ответ.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Это и сейчас база-знаний (со стороны компании). А со стороны некоторых участников, такие вопросы - быстрый способ фармить репу.
>   – *Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica*

Печальными последствиями может окончится ситуация, когда интересы компании расходятся с интересами сообщества. Ведь рано или поздно такое количество участников начнет составлять подавляющее большинство.

---

**PS** Мне казалось, что у любого, кто интересуется программированием, в крови обязана быть склонность к поиску и систематизации информации.

Comment: Данный ответ лишь точка зрения и констатация увиденного.

Comment: Это и сейчас база-знаний (со стороны компании). А со стороны некоторых участников, такие вопросы - быстрый способ фармить репу.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а кроме репы нам ничего и не дают-то. Что ещё делать тут, кроме как фармить репу?

Comment: @АндрейNOP помогать другим, например.

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica чем ответ на вопрос не помощь ?

Comment: Но ведь ответы разные. И в вопросе ничего плохого не вижу.