# Так какое на самом деле отношение у вас к простым вопросам и по какому принципу вы их минусуете и посылаете в гугл?

Tags: обсуждение

Ну, вопрос такой у меня назрел тут же. Какой-то новичок задал ну совсем элементарный вопрос: [ubuntu не видит файлы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452067/ubuntu-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b)

Я-то, как и andreymal, ответил на тот вопрос, но решил объяснить насчет простых вопросов. На что получил не лучшую вашу реакцию.

Мне одному кажется, что тут есть какие-то двойные стандарты? Тот вопрос вы не минусовали, никого в Гугл не посылали. А что же я получал в своих вопросах, причём заведомо более сложных?

1. [Ошибка SIGSEGV, что делать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1449580/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-sigsegv-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c) - 3 минуса. Угу-угу, причину SIGSEGV же так легко найти. (Ну или это мне надо освоить radare2 и valgrind)...
2. [Как создать EXT4 раздел с U-Boot?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1431908/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-ext4-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81-u-boot) - тут меня 0andriy посылал в Гугл: мол, глянь документацию. Кстати, потом я реально пошёл в гугл за документацией - и не нашёл её. Ага, надеюсь ты там каждый день 5 новых дистрибутивов собираешь, да ещё прямо под смартфоны. (Хотя в моём случае был OrangePi Lite, но сути не меняет)
3. [Как сравнить 3 числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420829/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-3-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) - 1 минус
4. [Что делать, если конфликтуют заголовки C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1419073/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-c) - 1 минус. Хотя тут, как в случае с SIGSEGV, "не очевидная проблема" - проблема с заголовками (ну откуда мне знать, что есть функция `partition()`). Конечно, и сам вопрос я задал слабовато, но все же.
5. [Где достать тулчейн под BSD?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1409855/%d0%93%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-bsd) - а за что, собственно, минус, я вообще не понимаю...

Вы уж определитесь: или вы как нелюбители простых вопросов посылаете в документацию и Гугл по поводу и без, или нормально реагируете.

Да и вы же на Мете поднимали вопрос по навыку гуглить: [Искусство гуглить и дубликаты, или почему нас минусуют](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7282/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%81%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82)

Честно, я в недоумении. По какому принципу вы посылаете в Гугл и документацию и минусуете вопросы - мне вообще непонятно. Вообще!

Я тут же, на ruMetaSO встречал такие ответы: дескать, вы не любите слишком простые вопросы, которые легко нагуглить. А тут такое... Я ничего не понимаю...

Comment: Сочувствую, развелось тут всяких ... (а правила изначально под других были заточены)

Comment: "Я-то, как и andreymal, ответил на тот вопрос, но решил объяснить насчет простых вопросов. На что получил не лучшую вашу реакцию." - в ответах на вопрос нужно отвечать на вопрос, а не поучать пользователей, что не нужно задавать простые вопросы, поэтому я ваш ответ отредактировал. Минус не ставил. В гугл в идеале отправлять не нужно. То что некоторые участники это делают - не значит что так нужно делать. В идеале участники должны придерживаться норм поведения: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/conduct , там конкретно про гугл упоминается.

Comment: По поводу ваших вопросов - вроде бы нормальные вопросы. Такое впечатление, что есть какой-то токсичный сишник, которому ваши вопросы почему-то не нравятся. А там где уже есть один минус - некоторые участники ставят и свой, что-то вроде ["теории разбитых окон"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD).

Comment: @insolor. imho это  стоит называть *стадным инстинктом* (и такое название скорее отвратит от этого занятия, нежели "теория разбитых окон")

Comment: @avp это никого не остановит. Минусование можно прекратить только отключением самой возможности минусовать.

Comment: Имхо, нормальный вопрос. Не идеальный, ну и что. Плюсанул. А вот ответ в духе «Неужели нельзя...» был плохим, его в комментарий переделали, и правильно.

Comment: Длинным объяснениям правил SO не место в ответах, пишите их в комментариях.

Comment: Вопросы типа «ubuntu не видит файлы» я не одобряю (считаю, что они бесполезно замусоривают базу знаний — достаточно прочитать любую статейку про файловую систему в линуксах), но так как они обычно соответствуют правилам — приходится терпеть. Вопросы типа «Ошибка SIGSEGV, что делать?» я не одобряю, потому что вопросы по отладке кода чаще всего бесполезны для всех кроме автора, но опять же зачем-то правилами разрешено. Остальные упомянутые вопросы вроде бы не такие уж и простые или бесполезные (хотя не исключено, что являются дубликатами, но мне лень разбираться)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ты к нам надолго вернулся?)

Comment: Вот сегодня... Каким должно быть отношение к такому [вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1454128/195342)?

Comment: Ну, тут уже реально за гранью...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Вопрос должен быть сформулирован, как обращение к живому человеку. Я не понимаю вопросов, у которых в заголовках "Ошибка 123, что делать?", а внутри просто код. Что делает этот код, что он должен делать, какой результат ожидается, и <s>что курил</s> о чем думал автор, пока этот код писал - надо разбираться отвечающему. Некоторые опытные участники оценивают такие вопросы как вопросы низкого качества и минусуют, или вообще закрывают.

**По пунктам**

- [Почему ls в Ubuntu не выводит никакие каталоги и файлы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1452067/373567) - это не ответ (тот что удалён, я его вижу), а скорее комментарий. Ответ должен быть каноничным, быть понятным не только автору вопроса, но и всем остальным кто его прочитал. Начинать ответ с фразы "Неужели нельзя было зайти в ту же папку с Windows?" определенно не стоило. Опирайтесь на факты и знания при ответе, а не на эмоции.
- [Ошибка SIGSEGV, что делать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1449580/373567) - не ленитесь объяснять историю, как до этого дошло. В начале вы просто запостили скриншот и дали код по ссылке, а не в теле вопроса. Ваш короткий комментарий внизу с дополнительной информацией позволил дать сразу верную ссылку. Есть шутка на тему объяснения проблемы:

  > - У меня не работает!
  > - Что не работает?
  > - Ничего не работает!
  > - А надо что?
  > - А надо чтобы работало!
- [Как создать EXT4 раздел с U-Boot?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1431908/373567) - мы не посылаем в гугл, комментатор не прав, здесь за это в особых случаях даже банят, даже меня банили разок. Флагайте комменты таких посыльных, модераторы накажут. Да, я иногда отправляю авторов вопросов читать, но только прямой ссылкой.
- [Как сравнить 3 числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1420829/2) *Язык - C, не C++, так что плюсовые решения не предлагать... Также не предлагать Windows-овые функции (работаю под Linux).* - у вас в тегах `linux` и `c`, зачем эта строчка? Поставил плюс, нормальный вопрос. Но опять же ответ не принят и никак не прокомментирован, он неправильный?
- [Что делать, если конфликтуют заголовки C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1419073/373567) - человек старался, писал ответ, а вы его не приняли, тем самым обозначили как бесполезный. Зато приняли самоответ, не надо так делать. Я в таких случаях удаляю свой ответ, даже если на нем есть голоса, ставлю минус автору вопроса и иду дальше. Принимайте ответы других участников, если они полезные.
- [Где достать тулчейн под BSD?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409855/373567) - К сожалению, иногда пролетают такие минусы, но снова ответ не принят и никак по существу не прокомментирован. Комментируйте неправильные ответы, принимайте правильные. Сейчас выглядит так, как-будто задал вопрос и забыл. Отвечающие тратят свое время на то чтобы вам помочь, не ленитесь дать фидбэк.

Требований к сложности вопросов здесь нет, и быть не может. Но вопросы сложности типа "что делает строчка `int c = 2 + 2`?" выглядят действительно странно. Если у вас возник подобный "простейший" вопрос, дополните его информацией, как именно вы пытались разобраться с этим вопросом, и что именно завело в тупик. Например "читал *тут*, гуглил *здесь*, но так и не разобрался, как работает `int`".

**Прочитайте это**

- [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - здесь всё по делу.
- [Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/373567) - здесь про то как не надо путать причину проблемы и симптомы

Comment: спасибо, что указали на мои ошибки там, где я их делал. Серьёзно, большое человеческое вам спасибо

Comment: @RandomDice779 не за что, рад, что всё понятно.

Comment: Тот кто ставит минусы, может объяснить, где я ошибся или опечатслся, чтобы исправить? Речь же не про мое личное мнение, а в целом про сообщество. Если вы не согласны, не стесняйтесь комментирвоать, всё обсуждаемо.

Answer (score 7):

**Вы зачем-то делаете неуместные обобщения. Получается, что вроде как и вопрос сейчас задали, и всех коллективно немного опустили. Тон у вас тоже не самый конструктивный, наглый. Ложные дилеммы ставите. Не надо так.**

Также не забывайте, что минус ставится не вам лично, а вопросу или ответу. Прочтите хинты к стрелкам вверх и вниз.

---

Я ваших вопросов и ответов ранее не видел, так что давайте пройдемся для примера (aepot уже все и так расписал впрочем):

0 - Вопрос плохо сформулирован. Что-то из серии "почему в папке нету файлов?", но в принципе для новичка, наверное, нормальный. +/- не ставлю. Улучшающие правки можете посмотреть. Ваш ответ весьма странный и по сути комментарий, а не ответ на вопрос. Согласен с оценкой aepot.

1 - Первоначальная версия вопроса достаточно плоха. Нету минимального кода в вопросе, скриншот вместо текста .. за такое тут минусуют. Вопрос заслуженно закрыт. Не минусую, но в первоначальной редакции минус бы легко поставил.

2 - Вам помогли с направлением поисков в комментариях. А вы теперь тут зачем-то дерзите.

3 - Достаточно банальный вопрос. Минус вполне могли поставить за это и за то что нет попытки собственного решения.

4 - Три минуса мне не совсем понятны, но судя по комментариям в чате, вы долго и настойчиво отказывались представить минимальный воспроизводимый пример кода. Сам вопрос сформулирован как общего плана - "Что делать если происходит А?" и вам дали такой ответ, а вы потом постите свой ответ "я сделал конкретное Б и все заработало". Такой ответ может получить минус.

5 - Вот тут поставил минус на вопрос. Вопрос кажется слишком размыт и наполнен жаргоном, в нем нет конкретики. Звучит почти как "где мне взять драм для жиги, а чо таково примусы же катят"

Comment: Была бы возможность поставить две галочки, поставил бы такое и на ваш ответ. К сожалению, и правда я не очень хорошо порой ищу в гугл или задаю вопросы на SO...

Comment: @RandomDice779 спаcибо за теплые слова. Главное, чтобы это вам помогло - задавать и отвечать, и пополнять Базу Знаний ruSO которая всем нам так помогает в работе и хобби =)

Comment: "Также не забывайте, что минус ставится не вам лично, а вопросу или ответу. Прочтите хинты к стрелкам вверх и вниз." – жаль, что это не все понимают. Мне так как-то один пользователь зашёл в профиль и все мои вопросы заминусовал просто по приколу...

Comment: @VladimirGonchar такие действия обычно достаточно быстро откатываются системой (там есть watchdog). Впрочем, если кто-то вас решит отблагодарить и поставить больше 3-5 плюсов подряд - тоже откатится.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar у вас кстати ссылка на гитхаб в профиле отдает 404