# Запрет "фриланса", навязывание "бинайса" и прочие угнетения

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, модерация, комментарии

В последнее время многие участники жалуются на острое непонимание некоторых решений или заявлений администрации. В том числе, и заявлений со [стороны администрации enSO](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7219/).

Если "навязывание" и "излишнюю заботу" о новичках можно было списать на завышенные требования к вежливости нашего КМ и модераторов — то как объяснить достаточно внезапные (для нас) решения на enSO? Не мог же наш КМ их всех покусать и заразить вирусом излишней вежливости? :)

## Формальные вопросы

- Почему [правило "будьте дружелюбными"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) не сводится к строчке "не материтесь", а расписано на целую страницу и помещено в раздел "Наша модель". Причем тут вообще модель?
- Почему запрещена грубость, даже в тех ситуациях, когда собеседник явно *заслуживает крепких слов*?
- Почему администрация предлагает не "посылать на фриланс", "не поучать" и вообще — быть не просто дружелюбными, а именно приветственными?
- Действительно ли администрация силой принуждает "старичков" к вежливости в угоду новичкам.

## Реальная причина

Игнорирование агрессии, иронии или сарказма в отношении даже исключительно плохих и ленивых авторов плохих вопросов приводит к снижению количества интересных и качественных вопросов.

## Длинное объяснение

[Barmaley описал существующее разделение как](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7257/177221):

> - опытным юзерам/экспертам здесь скучно
> - новичкам здесь некомфортно.

Под опытными подразумеваются местные эксперты-отвечающие. Под новичками — новые спрашивающие.

И да, такое разделение вроде как оправдывает существование выбора между "опытныe" "новички". Который администрация, почему-то, делает в пользу новичков.

Если прямо, то [многие пользователи воспринимают картину так](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7220/177221):

> Мы — хороший сайт, но создаётся впечатление недружелюбного, тут новичков ехидно тыкают за незнание правил некая Илитарная группа.
> Хватит это терпеть!
> Мы ужесточаем правила дружелюбия и толерантности, а ля: будь вежливым, сука!

Опять, две противопоставленных категории — "Илита" vs "новички".

## Чуть более реальная картина

Сообщество у нас вполне дружелюбное. Нет разделения на "злую элиту" и "новичков".
Если вы заглянете в первый попавшийся вопрос — то вы, скорее всего, не увидите ни хамства, ни угнетения негров, ни ненависти к женщинам, ни прочего, описанного в статье (если вдруг увидите — ставьте флаг :).

Но и на enSO, и на ruSO есть особенности структуры сообщества, ради которых и введены достаточно жесткие правила.

В любом QA-сообществе, на любом форуме есть две категории отвечающих:

- опытные юзеры/эксперты, которым скучно, и которые отвечают на редкие, интересные лично им, вопросы
- новые отвечающие, которые отвечают на все подряд.

У новых отвечающих — медовый месяц с сайтом. Они отвечают вообще на все. От явных дубликатов до домашки. Они радуются каждой медальке. Они следят за своей репутацией, и возмущаются на мете при получении своего первого минуса.

Т.е. разделение у нас:

- Опытные юзеры, которые скучают и отвечают на интересное
- Подрастающая смена, которая отвечает на все подряд
- Новички, которым неуютно, и которые задают вопросы непредсказуемого качества

## Опытные пользователи почти не сталкиваются с давлением "будьте дружелюбными"

Основное давление применяется к "подрастающей смене".

По банам:

- Медиана репутации на момент получения предупреждения — 950.
- Медиана репутации на момент получения бана — 1050.

<sub>Данные от @Qwertiy, я перебрал вручную примерно треть, оставил именно отвечающих на вопросы.</sub>

Медиана репутации по удаленным комментариям — 1500.

<sub>Данные от Nicolas Chabanovsky, учитывались комментарии за последние 30 дней. Репутация взята на данный момент, так что реальная медиана на момент оставления коммента — ниже.</sub>

Внезапно, под "be-nice" в основном попадают не опытные старички от 10K репутации, а те, кто даже не добрался до [базовых инструментов модерирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

70% из тех, чьи комментарии удаляли как "невежливые" — не набрали и 3000 репутации.

---

## Шаблон развития проблемы

- Опытные юзеры хорошо оценивают вопрос, и хорошо понимают намерения топикастера. Да, очередной притащивший домашку на SO вызывает у них злость. Но они опытные, и ограничиваются саркастичным комментарием.
- Подрастающая смена видит сарказм по отношению к задающим, неправильно понимает его причину. Все же однозначно — пришел старичок и "научил новичка правильно задавать вопросы". Пожестче надо быть с этими нубами!

И возникают примерно такие диалоги:

> - В: Как сделать то-то. Вопрос с кодом. Читал комментарии на сторонних сайтах, говорят что не возможно :(
> - О: Больше читайте и меньше думайте.

> - В: вопрос про окончания к числам,  1-ый, 2-ой, 3-ий, 4-ый, 5-ый
> - О: В школе склонениям не учили? В поиске этого навалом.

---

Даже если "подрастающие" понимают причины "жесткости" и сарказма — они сталкиваются с проблемой оценки качества вопроса. У опытных старичков чаще всего
злость вызывает "домашка". Домашку относительно легко распознать. По крайней мере, можно [попытаться придумать формальный критерий для нее](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4992/177221).

Но "подрастающие" пока еще плохо различают, какой вопрос действительно плох, а какой — просто требует правки. Но они уже освоились на сайте, и хотят влиять на его развитие видеть больше качественных вопросов. Так что они используют единственный доступный им инструмент — агрессию в комментариях — чтобы убрать *плохой* вопрос с глаз долой. Вместе с автором. И тут появляется *злой модератор* или КМ, и *принуждает к be-nice* del, del, del, предупреждение, бан!

Что же пошло не так? Почему старичкам вроде как можно проявлять сарказм, а им — нельзя?

У нас есть механизм закрытия вопросов, не соответствующих теме. Для закрытия требуется 5 голосов от участников с репутацией больше 3000. Если посмотреть на историю очереди закрытия — видно, что часто вопросы оставляют открытыми, и что решение разных участников по многим вопросам неоднозначно.

"Небинайсные подрастающие" этот механизм закрытия обходят. Т.е. они:

- Отпугивают задающих вопросы с сайта (и хороших, и плохих)
- Часто делают это совершенно необосновано (т.к. сами не знают правил)
- Делают это единолично, на свое личное усмотрение

Принудительная единоличность решения — эта одна из причин, по которой модераторы избегают очередей проверок на закрытие. Шанс, что модератор не угадает, и единолично снесет с сайта хороший вопрос — слишком велик. Но мы, почему-то, позволяем делать то же самое участникам, которые даже не могут проголосовать за закрытие.

## Последствия

Неожиданно, но *действуя из лучших побуждений* они *снижают среднее качество вопросов*.

- Наглым, ненавистным, халявщикам-задающим *все равно* на злобные комментарии. Плохих вопросов меньше не станет.
- Из-за частых ошибок и непонимания правил они отпугивают потенциально хороших задающих вопросы. Хороших вопросов становится меньше.

Да, опытные участники редко применяют сарказм *необоснованно*. Но вот подрастающее поколение — многократно усиливает его, и направляет наугад на все подряд. Срабатывает старая добрая [теория разбитых окон](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD) — и уже никого не волнует, что первое окно разбила опытная полиция при задержании хулигана.

## Что делать?

Администрация вынуждена с этим бороться. К сожалению, нельзя сформулировать правило "будьте дружелюбными" так, чтобы разрешить грубость и сарказм, и при этом исключить массовые ложные срабатывания. Я сомневаюсь, что правило "можно проявлять сарказм после получения знака за 1000 проверок" будет достаточно честным.

Отсюда и "будьте дружелюбными" а не просто "не хамите", и запрет "фриланса" (очень большой % ложных срабатываний), и, иногда затрагивающее старичков, принуждение.

Если этот фильтр и давление на "до-3к" убрать — и качество, и поток вопросов падает. Старичкам становится еще скучнее. Они начинают проявлять сарказм сильнее.
Подрастающие видят это, *стараются сильнее*, еще чаще выбрасывают вопросы (в том числе и хорошие). И начинается коллапс.

Есть хороший способ улучшить качество вопросов без усиления риска выбросить что-то действительно стоящее — это просмотр очередей закрытия. Это действительно эффективный механизм и для улучшения качества вопросов, и для убирания с сайта всякого мусора.

Если хотите видеть интересные вопросы — пожалуйста, помогите модерировать сайт. Сарказм не поможет.

Comment: Хороший анализ. А вот с выводами я не согласен. IMHO надо закрывать поменьше, попросту не обращать внимания на всякую дурь и она сама уйдет с глаз долой. С авторами не слишком удачно сформулированных  вопросов надо общаться в комментариях (и ответах), стремясь их итеративно  улучшить. Видя же такое отношение (это и есть то самое *дружелюбие*) и раскритикованные начинающие отвечать станут вести себя по другому.

Comment: В вашем вопросе нет вопроса. Но он хорош! =)

Comment: Только я вот уверен, что спрашивающие новички очень редко становятся отвечающими. Хотелось бы увидеть статистику: "сколько вопросов задано участником давшим первый/сотый ответ", сколько ответов дано участником задавшим первый/сотый вопрос. Мне кажется это всё абсолютно разные люди, их нужно изначально рассматривать как две разные ЦА.

Comment: @vp_arth  спрашивающие новички, и свежие отвечающие - да,  две разные ЦА, почти не пересекающиеся. Суть в том,  что под удаление комментов и баны попадают именно "чуть-чуть освоившиеся отвечающие", за то,  что они начинают себя не слишком вежливо вести с "новичками-спрашивающими". Новички-спрашивающие - это основной источник вопросов.

Comment: @vp_arth в движке есть способ временно спрятать и отсортирвать вопросы от совсем новичков - triage. Может быть стоит его включить.

Comment: Считаю, что первые вопросы самые важные. От них зависит, как новичок оценит ресурс.

Comment: Временное отключение позволит отредактировать вопрос до того, как его увидят остальные... Фича интересная, но довольно спорная. Можно вынести этот вопрос на голосование, но действительно ли у нас столько проблем со свежими вопросами? Мне кажется, что редактируемые итак редактируются, а в случае недостатка информации, временное сокрытие не поможет.

Comment: @PashaPash, triage же ничего не прячет - просто плюс очередь для раскидывания по другим очередям. Бесполезная штука для нас.

Comment: @Qwertiy triage прячет с [home page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/), и unsalvagable там включает в том числе и "Obviously a duplicate of some question you can find with about 15 seconds searching? The output of someone's cat dancing merrily across their keyboard?" :)

Answer (score 10):

Я бы хотел добавить следующее.

Я в целом согласен с фактажом, но мне трудно согласиться с выводами. Отвечать на неправильные слова следует убеждением, а не административными мерами. Да, это сложнее и тяжелее, проще всего тупо забанить и удалить комментарии. Но самое простое решение — не всегда лучшее.

Комментарии под вопросом — позитивные или негативные — являются существенной частью воспитания пользователей (как новых, так и старых) тому, какие вопросы у нас считаются хорошими, а какие — нет. Удаление комментариев служит сомнительной и очень лицемерной цели поддержать видимость отсутствия проблемы, и мешает видеть участникам, какие вопросы у нас приветствуются, а какие нет, мешает, таким образом, преемственности понимания цели и задач сайта, и его внутренних консенсусов.

А это неформальное обучение намного более важно, чем формальные правила. Ведь никто из нормальных, живых людей из мяса и костей не хочет читать длинные скучные своды правил!

Вспомните, когда вы в последний раз читали документацию к программе с GUI — если программа не ведёт себя интуитивно понятным образом, вы справедливо считали её плохо написанной. Так и с правилами на сайте: если нету правильного, интуитивно понятного фидбэка на плохо заданный вопрос — не в виде невидимой новичкам разбалловки плюсов и минусов, а в виде комментария, объясняющего, что же не так с вопросом — то даже добросовестные участники будут воспринимать плохие вопросы как легитимные. Таким фидбэком и являются комментарии.

Следовательно, стратегия страуса, заключающаяся в подчистке неприятных комментариев, ошибочна, ухудшает качество вопросов и должна быть пересмотрена. Критическому комментарию должно быть место около плохого вопроса. [Кстати, как и хвалебному. Когда вы в последний раз оставляли комментарий, в котором хвалили хорошо заданный новичковый вопрос? Если ответ — «никогда», не говорите мне, что вы боретесь за качество сайта.]

А как же бороться с несправедливыми комментариями, которые ругают вполне хороший вопрос? А так же, как и в нормальной жизни, где у вас нет возможности  забанить ненравящееся вам мнение: **словами**! Оставьте антитезисный комментарий, в котором скажите, что вопрос хороший, и что негативные комментарии там совершенно зря. Пристыдите нерадивого комментатора. Отстаивайте свою позицию. Деритесь за качество с открытым забралом! Такая позиция намного честнее, и, поверьте, заработает вам куда больше авторитета, чем тупое административное принуждение. [Нет времени на это? Тогда что вы делаете на сайте?]

Бан и стирание комментариев должно быть реально крайним средством. Бить в ответ на слова — нехорошо. Применяйте тяжёлую артиллерию, когда видите мат или угрозы.

Comment: В случае недружелюбных комментариев, своего рода "драма" или "воспитательная" переписка должна быть на основном сайте рядом с техническими постами?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Разумеется. Идея о том, что можно отделить техническую сторону от социальной — мертворожденная утопия. [Да, это не должно переходить в перепалку. В этом случае необходимо перевести разговор в чат.]

Comment: Не уверен, что это нужно, в том числе и другим людям. А если удалить комментарий и объяснить его автору, почему он удалён и в чём именно автор ведёт себя некорректно, так будет плохо?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov: Критика без мата допустима, не вижу причин её удалять. Критиковать не некорректно, некорректно материться и угрожать. На критику надо отвечать контркритикой, а не тупо сносить непонравившееся мнение.

Comment: У этого варианта есть существенный недостаток - убеждаемый обычно *уверен*, что он действует правильно. Особенно если он многократно видел раньше то же самое в исполнении участников с кучей репутации. Т.е. он обычно считает что "тут так принято", он считает что причина видимого им сарказма - в том, что вопрос задал новичок (а не в том, что вопрос плохой). Т.е. порицать и исправлять таких таких грубиянов должны или модераторы, или топы. И то - я пару раз пробовал. Знаете, какая реакция? Дословно "это *ВЫ* решили что не учат или где-то написано? Учат, ещё как учат Но не всех".

Comment: @PashaPash: Значит, найдите аргументы поубедительнее, чем «здесь так не принято, и точка». Задача должна быть переубедить, а не запретить. Я понимаю, что это непросто, но у вас есть много времени оттачивать аргументацию (не сработает на этом — сработает через 10 раз), а остальные пришли в первый раз. // И да, один комментарий против плохого комментария уже вызывает разумные сомнения в читающем, сразу видно, что консенсуса «топить и закрывать» нет. // Ну и — сагитируйте топов на евангелизацию правил, да.

Comment: @VladD и да, его комментарий "затем, чтобы научить задавать вопросы" - начинают плюсовать другие участники, которые думают, что да, новичков надо поучать.

Comment: @PashaPash: Ну это я придумал сходу, и возможно, это как-то неизящно. Ну так если ничего не приходит в голову, можно обратиться к сообществу в чате, пусть придумают хороший метод объяснить. В любом случае, ваш комментарий должен быть на голову выше и «прикольнее» обидного комментария.

Comment: [Перенес обсуждение в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77395/discussion-between-pashapash-and-vladd).

Answer (score 8):

> Игнорирование агрессии, иронии или сарказма в отношении даже исключительно плохих и ленивых авторов плохих вопросов приводит к снижению количества интересных и качественных вопросов.

Для короткого варианта — довольно спорное утверждение. И почему именно игнорирование?

---

## Про перегибы с бинайсовостью

> У новых отвечающих — медовый месяц с сайтом. Они отвечают вообще на все. От явных дубликатов до домашки. Они радуются каждой медальке. Они следят за своей репутацией, и возмущаются на мете при получении своего первого минуса.

Не очень уверен, что новым отвечающим всё равно, на что отвечать, но это неважно. Да, они следят за репутацией и медальками и расстраиваются из-за минусов. И вот к этому последнему факту мы ещё вернёмся.

> Медиана репутации на момент получения предупреждения — 950.
>   Медиана репутации на момент получения бана — 1050.

Посмотрел медиану репутации активных на сайте пользователей (под активными понимаются пользователи, посетившие сайт в течение последнего месяца, но давшие свой первый ответ более месяца назад). Посмотрел [её зависимость от числа данных ответов](//data.stackexchange.com/ru/revision/850876/1050607/#graph) (Median50 — это медиана по пользователям, набравшим хотя бы 50 баллов — минимальный уровень, позволяющий писать комментарии под чужими сообщениями вне своих вопросов — как видно, она почти не отличается от обычной начиная с 4 ответов):

[image: зависимость медианы репутации от числа ответов]

Получается, эти значения равны медиане по сайту среди активных пользователей, давших не менее 14 ответов.

> Медиана репутации по удаленным комментариям — 1500.

А вот это интересно. Медиана вдруг выросла в полтора раза и соответствует медиане активных пользователей, давших не менее 25 ответов. Мы сдвигаем планку на целых 10 ответов (а это 71% от 14) вверх! Откуда же такой сдвиг?

Не проверял, но выглядит как будто куча корректных комментариев (ведь даже предупреждение не было выслано) более опытных участников тихонечко зачищается как оскорбления.

> Внезапно, под "be-nice" в основном попадают не опытные старички от 10K репутации, а те, кто даже не добрался до базовых инструментов модерирования

Да ну? Мы рассматриваем все тревоги по оскорблениям, среди которых есть как реальные оскорбления, так и навязываемый бинайс, которому сопротивляется сообщество. Менее опытные пользователи попадают под первую часть и получают предупреждения и баны, а более опытные — под чистку нейтральных комментариев. Просто на основе того, кто сообщения получает, а кто нет.

Чему сопротивляется сообщество? Хочет ли оно разрешить оскорбления? Нет. Хочет ли прекратить необоснованную чистку? Да. По идее, вторая медиана (по удаляемым комментариям), должна быть ниже первой (по числу предупреждений). Это бы означало, что мы сначала зачищаем сомнительные сообщения и через несколько штук (за это время пользователь успеет дать пару ответов и увеличить медиану) высылаем предупреждение.

А то, что наблюдаем сейчас как раз отражает значительные чистки допустимого контента.

> 70% из тех, чьи комментарии удаляли как "невежливые" — не набрали и 3000 репутации.

70% от 1500 — это 1050. Какое-то не случайное совпадение при линейном росте.
Вероятно, мы как раз обсуждаем оставшиеся 30% (что, кстати, не мало — почти треть!).

---

## Про поставленные цели

> Подрастающая смена видит сарказм по отношению к задающим, неправильно понимает его причину. Все же однозначно — пришел старичок и "научил новичка правильно задавать вопросы". Пожестче надо быть с этими нубами!

Выглядит правдоподобно. Но есть но.

> Но "подрастающие" пока еще плохо различают, какой вопрос действительно плох, а какой — просто требует правки. Но они уже освоились на сайте, и хотят влиять на его развитие видеть больше качественных вопросов. Так что они используют единственный доступный им инструмент — агрессию в комментариях — чтобы убрать плохой вопрос с глаз долой. Вместе с автором. И тут появляется злой модератор или КМ, и принуждает к be-nice del, del, del, предупреждение, бан!

Неправда. Не единственный:

- Чтобы [голосовать против](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) — надо всего 125 баллов репутации
- Чтобы [поставить тревогу](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), в том числе, с целью закрыть вопрос, надо и того меньше — всего 15 баллов

Напоминаю, что [для написания комментария](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) в чужом вопросе надо 50 баллов.

Получается, пользователь сможет закрывать (не непосредственно, но отправлять в очередь) гораздо раньше, чем комментировать. Но это почти не страшно, потому что понадобится ошибка ещё 5 высокореповых человек, чтобы закрыть хороший вопрос.

Затем он сможет комментировать. Предположим, что у нас тут идеальный бинайс и написать какой-то недружелюбный коммент ему даже в голову не придёт (ну мы же к этому стремимся?). Но вопрос он будет по-прежнему считать плохим. Да и никак не узнает, что он хороший, потому что он никому не скажет, что вопрос плохой, а значит ему никто и не ответит, что вопрос хороший.

Вскоре он получает право голосовать портив. И вот тут раз! Вопросы-то плохие, надо ставить минусы. Минусы никак не проверяются (пользователи разные, серийных голосований нет, всё в соответствии со штатной работой сайта), участник по-прежнему не в курсе, что плохо относится к хорошим вопросам и продолжает их минусовать.

Приходят новые участники, они видят, какие вопросы минусуются и идут по описанному пути.

А потом они получают доступ к очередям проверок и начинают эти вопросы закрывать.

**Итак, что же получилось? Мы пришли к варианту enSO, на котором есть вылизанные бинайсовые комментарии, но любые новые простые вопросы отправляются в минус и на закрытие, хотя аналогичные вопросы 10-летней давности в огромном плюсе.**

Неужели это то, чего мы хотим достичь? :'(

---

## А как можно по-другому?

Откатываемся к зачистке комментариев, а именно к

> Так что они используют единственный доступный им инструмент — агрессию в комментариях — чтобы убрать плохой вопрос с глаз долой.

Как уже выяснили, не единственный. Но, предположим, используют.

Должен быть какой-то предел, за который переступать нельзя. Удаление недопустимого комментария, предупреждение, при множественном повторении — бан. Независимо от репутации, но в зависимости от контекста. Например, вряд ли надо банить за агрессию в ответ на агрессию — достаточно просто предупредить, если участник в других местах агрессивно себя не ведёт.

> К сожалению, нельзя сформулировать правило "будьте дружелюбными" так, чтобы разрешить грубость и сарказм, и при этом исключить массовые ложные срабатывания.

Да, естественно есть ещё и ошибки, когда новые участники будут на хорошие вопросы плохо реагировать в комментариях. И это хорошо! Мы увидим, что у человека неправильное понимание качества вопроса и сможем прям там же под вопросом ответить на его комментарий, что он не прав и пояснить, почему (желательно даже дать ссылку на тему на мете, относящуюся к конкретному случаю). Таким образом мы сможем отслеживать отношение к вопросам и направлять его в нужное русло.

Будет ли автор сообщения, под которым необоснованно написали саркастический комментарий, чувствовать что-то плохое? На мой взгляд нет, ведь вот как это будет смотреться: какой-то новичок написал что-то не очень позитивное, а потом пришёл участник с большей репутацией и дружелюбно показал новичку, что тот ошибается. Автора поста, скорее всего, ощутит, что тут его защищают и тут ему рады. Вроде это и есть наша цель.

Будет ли автор необоснованного комментария чувствовать что-то плохое? Скорее всего нет. Во-первых, он уже будет видеть подобное по мере набора репутации. до того, как сам сможет комментировать, что тоже поможет ему сориентироваться, какие вопросы не стоит считать плохими и так комментировать. Во-вторых, ответный комментарий будет вежливым и со ссылкой на подробное описание — он будет понимать, что это более-менее объективная оценка и подсказка и она не основана на неприязни или отторжении.

Надо ли удалять такие комментарии? Как я уже сказал выше, сразу их зачищать не надо. Однако очевидно, что и вечно их держать смысла обычно нет. Полагаю, тут вполне можно руководствоваться стандартными правилами устаревания комментариев. Т. е. если его кто-то через месяц случайно заметит и поставит тревогу, что он устарел, то его надо удалить (ну если там не было чего-то интересного, что хотелось бы сохранить).

> Если хотите видеть интересные вопросы — пожалуйста, помогите модерировать сайт. Сарказм не поможет.

Наоборот, именно он и поможет, потому что он — единственное видимое проявление отношение пользователя к вопросу, на которое мы можем среагировать. Мы не реагируем на очередь закрытия — там должна быть совсем жесть, чтобы сработала автоматика и выставила временный запрет на проверку, но сами мы никогда не проверяем тех, кто отправляет туда вопросы (а некоторое время назад [18% отправляемых туда вопросов не получали ни единого голоса за закрытие](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2782/178988)); а отношение к ответам даже очередями не покрывается. Мы не видим голоса и не знаем, кто и что минусует — тут даже теоретической возможности обратиться к участнику нет.

**Нам крайне важно сохранить единственный видимый фидбек о качестве сообщений — саркастические комментарии.**

Comment: disclaimer: я не утверждаю, что запрет сарказма и прочее - это единственный и правильный путь. Я просто пытался как-то разрешить непонимание определенных решений администрации. Я не утверждаю, что они - единственно верные :)

Comment: Из технических замечаний - медиана по тревогам сдвинута вверх, примерно на репутацию за пол месяца (т.к. бралась репутация на текущий момент). Допишу в ответ.

Comment: @PashaPash, ну значит для первой части ответа в вопросе нужна верная статистика, а у меня её нет... Возможно, полмесяца действительно где-то близко к тем 10 вопросам разницы.

Comment: Статистика удалённых комментариев без причины удаления - ничтожна. Причина "более не необходим" не вносит ничего негативного в "кредитную историю" автора. + к этому есть самоудалённые комментарии - по сути та же категория.

Comment: @vp_arth, причина удаления - "невежливый или оскорбительный" (с погрешностью, что флаг стоял, а снесли всё в чат), впрочем это надо было под вопросом спрашивать, а не у меня.

Comment: @Qwertiy То есть дать обратную связь о  проблемах с качествах без  сарказма, по вашему мнению, — нереалистично?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну предлагай ещё варианты.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вообще просто: дать обратную связь в посте или комментарие без сарказма. Никогда с этим проблем не было.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ты на что-то не на то её давать собрался. Речь не про обратную связь на вопрос, а про обратную связь на неправильное отношение к вопросу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Сарказм тогда не поможет, только всё усугубит.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, почему мне кажется, что ты ответ не читал? ((( 4 абзаца после предпоследней цитаты.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хорошо, я его перечитал, и как оказалось, не зря. Я сперва не понял задумки объяснить тому, кто неверно ведёт себя в комментариях, думал вы просто предлагаете подшучивать в комментриях.:) По поводу разъяснений — согласен. Но поводу оставить эти комментарии — категорически против.

Comment: @Qwertiy  Теперь другой вопрос, зачем оставлять "саркастические комментарии". А если автора вопрос они всё-таки заденут? Почему мы должны исходить из предположения, раз комментарий необоснован, то не должно задевать?

Comment: минус за "сохранить сарказм" -- ядовитый комментарии, плодят ядовитые комментарии (люди, которые могли бы себя вежливо вести, заражаются, что нездоровую атмосферу создаёт). Есть более конструктивная альтернатива: если на вопрос в текущем виде нельзя ответить, голосуйте за закрытие; если вы видите как вопрос можно улучшить оставьте специфичный для вопроса комментарий (как именно этот вопрос можно улучшить) или даже сами правку сделайте (к примеру, часто можно добавить более информативный заголовок); если сил не хватает, то просто минус плохому вопросу поставьте (вот вам 3 вида feedback)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov 1. Если ответить и удалить комментарий, на который отвечаешь, то висящий ни с того, ни с сего коммент "Вася, ты не прав, вопрос хороший" - это какая-то фигня. 2. Автора удалённого комментария нельзя позвать через @ - т. е. твой ответ даже не прочитают. 3. Удалять можно, но не сразу. И как неактуальные, а не как грубые.

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно написать комментарий через "собачку", потом удалить.

Comment: @jfs, ещё раз. Вопрос хороший, а оценивающий не прав. К чему приведёт твой вариант, расписано во второй секции ("Про поставленные цели").

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, вроде сайт не гарантирует, что уведомление придёт - если повезёт, то да, а если нет - то нет. В любом случае, висящий ответный комментарий при удалённом комментарии, на который отвечали - это ерунда.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не согласен, приведу привер https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/823119/#comment1311956_823125. Чем комментарий плох?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, ну, там хотя бы другие его комментарии есть, чтобы он уведомление получил. А так - вроде годится.

Answer (score 3):

Согласен. В целом.

Давление на старичков не из-за нарушения, а из-за того, что они являются триггером... среднячков оправдано, видимо, оно так и есть.

Но давайте представим что будет с абсолютным бинайсом:
Старички видят плохой вопрос, усилием воли закрывают вкладку (возможно поставив тревогу/подобное. Но тихо, без сарказма!).
Приходит среднячок/новичок не видит видимых проявлений недовольства, начинает считать что тут так принято и такой формат разрешён.
Но он не знает что в комментах могли быть страшного вида оргии, но их **не видно**, ибо они тихо снесены теми самыми старичками/модерами.

В итоге с сарказмом плохо (лавинный эффект, теория разбитых окон), но и без него плохо (нет никакого критерия о качестве вопроса (новички же пропускают "Закрыть (4)" мимо глаз)).

Может стоит поискать баланс между, найти эффективный способ доносить Правила, а не просто бинайсить в надежде что это поможет?

---

Расчищать очередь - это борьба с последствием, а не причиной. Как мы знаем, бороться надо с последней.

P. S. Старичкам нужно где-то выпускать пар, а то вдруг на сотом плохом вопросе, где он бинайсил его прорвёт так на сарказм/едкость, что в бан улетит, дабы успокоиться.

Comment: Откровенный спам улетает по тревогам за пять-десять минут. Английский язык и домашка держится максимум полчаса. Новички в целом задают нормальные вопросы - что их носом в правила тыкать? (Если вам кажется, что плохих новичков много - просто перестаньте разгребать авгиевы очереди проверок, там слишком большой сгусток) А плохие новички огребают и минуса и закрывашки и иронию и ещё от модераторов предупреждения.

Comment: *`"... вдруг на сотом плохом вопросе, где он бинайсил его прорвёт так на сарказм/едкость ..."`* -- а не лучше, если не нравится вопрос просто пройти мимо?

Comment: @avp, так в этом и суть - недовольство копится, а выплеснуть "небинайсно". И, рано или поздно, просто пройти мимо не выйдет...

Comment: Насчёт "старичкам нужно где-то выпускать пар" - это вы завернули. Я лично не хочу приходить в какое-то место, где старичок, на которого наорал на работе начальник будет на мне отыгрываться.

Comment: @AK, пар не в целом (это другая проблема), а именно на плохие вопросы.

Comment: [Если у вас не хватает времени на вежливость, лучше предоставить слово тому, у кого есть это время.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44471798#44471798)

Comment: *новички же пропускают "Закрыть (4)" мимо глаз* — они ж его вообще не видят? Надо 3000 реп.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, Даже не знаю. Может видят, но не могут проголосовать. Но если не видят - ещё хуже, ещё меньше признаков для "плохих" вопросов.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions Не видят

Comment: @АндрейNOP Это не так, после 250 репутации можно видеть чужие голоса за закрытие на своеём вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, речь, вроде, не о своих вопросах идет

Comment: @АндрейNOP, О любых. Не радужно - автор плохого вопроса явно не будет заморачиваться на этот счёт, а среднячки не увидят маркера плохости.