# Как считаете, есть ли необходимость в отдельном разделе сайта, предназначенном под учебные и т.п. вопросы?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

StackOverflow подразумевает помощь в решении проблем/вопросов при условии, что вопрос [**задан корректно**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (включает в себя понятное **описание проблемы** и **демонстрацию попытки самостоятельного решения**) и не дублирует уже существующий вопрос.

Зачастую, если оба условия не будут соблюдены, то на такой вопрос не будут отвечать и/или закроют и закидают отрицательными оценками. И только в редких случаях на такой вопрос кто-то может дать ответ с подробными объяснениями.

Я сам являюсь участником ruStackOverflow 2 года и стараюсь придерживаться принятых в сообществе правил и отвечаю очень подробно и развернуто только на правильно (или почти) сформированные вопросы, но тоже изредка могу ответить на вопрос, по факту представляющий из себя запрос на готовый код.

**[В одной из старых тем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7257/373173)** уже писали о том, что когда часто видишь повторяющиеся вопросы "*Непроизвольно рождается агрессия, ирония, сарказм и т.д.*". Мне все это знакомо, особенно в тех случаях, когда расписываешь максимально подробный ответ с доп. информацией, позволяющей и стимулирующей расширять свои познания в определенной области, а в ответ тебе присылают текст ошибки, потому что человек не смог правильно вставить код из ответа к себе и даже не стал разбираться как там что работает...

---

Так вот, к чему все это.

Иногда, смотря или отвечая на такие вопросы, вспоминаю себя 2 года назад, когда я по началу тоже не понимал почему мой вопрос стремятся закрыть и снизить рейтинг или как-то съязвить, ведь я же просто ожидал что разбирающиеся люди, при желании смогут решить мою проблему.

По факту, такие вопросы нужно задавать на других сайтах, но что вы думаете об идее о том, чтобы создать какой-то отдельный раздел для учебных и прочих "неправильных вопросов", где на них все же смогут дать ответ, вместо того, чтобы удалять их.

---

*Пока писал, кажется понял, что идея не несет смысла и пользы, но, может удастся как-то ее развить?*

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что люди, пришедшие за срочным решением своей узкой проблемы, станут разбираться, в какой раздел поместить свой вопрос, т.е. постоянно, по моему мнению, придётся переносить их в раздел "Срочно решите мою проблему". Возможен и обратный случай, когда хороший вопрос нового участника окажется в этом *неугодном* разделе. Раз это менее привилегированный раздел сайта, то отвечающих потенциально там должно быть меньше (если только репутации там больше давать не будут). Да и общий поиск вопросов по сайту каким образом следует реализовать (например, при отметке вопроса дубликатом)?

Comment: В целом при абсолютно верной реализации и абсолютном исполнении установленных правил или автоматизированном определении раздела, которому должен принадлежать вопрос, эта идея мне кажется не совсем плохой. Но мы же не в вакууме. В конце концов, очевидный запрос фриланса и так закрывается, а минусы участникам с репутацией меньше 2 не страшны

Comment: Правильная идея. К сожалению, сейчас может быть реализована только присваиванием соответствующих меток. Далее нам всем надо просто договориться, что к вопросам с такими метками нужно подходить снисходително и т.д. ...

Comment: Если вопрос чисто лабораторка - то им в целом не место ни на каких разделах. Во-перых сделать за кого-то - это фриланс. Иначе такие ленивцы тут налетят как пчёлки и сами не будут учится, отсюда Во-вторых - таких "специалистов" нам (в сообществе IT) не нужно, я считаю, иначе вообще зачем туда шли? А потом ракеты падают и приложения жрут память как бегемоты и зависают от калькулятора и обрушивают банковские сектора и допускают неточности в расчётах для хирурга и убивают людей....нет спасибо. Любители халявы - опасные для всех сфер и лучше таких не поддерживать

Comment: Как много противоречий, при этом не могу ни с кем не согласиться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У всех сайтов только 2 раздела - основной и мета.

Так что в любом случае, дождаться от разработчиков ещё раздел(ы) нереально.

Вообще, что касается деления сайта на разделы, то я идею поддерживаю, впрочем, не в том виде, как предлагается в вопросе.

Comment: Существует, ли, описание делений сайта, которые вы поддерживаете? В каком виде?

Comment: @Dmitry, нет, я его письменно нигде не формулировал.

Comment: Есть в планах формулировать? Проблема актуальна и большАя часть пользователей приходит сюда именно за этим. Задержать бы какую-то часть, которые действительно хотят решать, вникать и чему то научиться.

Comment: @Dmitry, ну не знаю, может как-нибудь напишу. Всё равно ведь тут не реализуют...